# Quais as principais diferenças entre um computador quântico e um computador convencional?

Tags: teoria-da-computação

Dizem que a computação quântica irá revolucionar a computação caso seja implementada de maneira bem sucedida. Por que isso? Quais as principais diferenças entre um computador quântico e um computador convencional que tornariam o primeiro muito mais rápido?

Comment: Não sei falar das diferenças, mas um dos maiores *impactos* que a computação quântica traria seria sobre a segurança: não só ela abre novas possibilidades que hoje não existem, como também torna obsoletas várias técnicas das quais os sistemas atuais dependem enormemente, como as empregadas pelo SSL/TLS (seja RSA ou Curvas Elípticas). Alguns problemas até então considerados *NP-Hard* - como a fatoração - poderiam ser resolvidos em tempo polinomial dado um número suficiente de qbits. Um cenário desses demandaria um *upgrade* em larga escala para que a internet continuasse razoavelmente segura.

Comment: @mgibsonbr você saberia explicar por que/como com a computação quântica esses problemas NP-hard conseguiriam ser resolvidos em tempo polinomial?

Comment: Mas os algoritmos de criptografia seriam também quânticos ...

Comment: Seria interessante voce pesquisar artigos no google de preferencia artigos em ingles, pra isso que eles servem. São mt bons. Pois aqui voce vera mt acho e nao acho dizem ou n dizem, nos artigos os autores provam o pq isso e aquilo. ctza lendo  um dois ou tres artigos vc ja tera ctza como funciona computaçao quantica

Comment: Fazendo isso você mesmo podera responder essa pergunta citando fontes(links) de texto que você leu.

Comment: Carlos, eu não saberia dizer isso em geral, mas no caso específico da fatoração há o [algoritmo de Shor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm). A relação entre as classes NP e BQP é um problema em aberto. @Motta Sim, há bastante pesquisa no assunto [criptografia pós-*quantum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-quantum_cryptography), incluindo algoritmos "normais" que são resistentes à computação quântica (a propósito, os hashes e a criptografia simétrica já o são, em sua maior parte). Como falei no meu 1º comentário, o problema é de natureza prática: o custo de um *upgrade* massivo.

Comment: @mgibson: fatoração NÃO é um problema NP-hard! A complexidade exata ainda é um problema em aberto mas o consenso é de que o problema  da fatoração provavelmente tem complexidade intermediária, acima de P mas abaixo de NP-completo. Além disso até hoje não se sabe de nenhum problema NP completo que seja resolvido em tempo polinomial por um algoritmo quântico e existem evidências de que isso talvez seja impossível. [dê uma olhada na tabela na pag 6 desse pdf](http://cs.virginia.edu/~robins/The_Limits_of_Quantum_Computers.pdf)

Comment: @hugomg [Estou vendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Difficulty_and_complexity)... Na faculdade me disseram que era NP-hard, mas isso faz mais de 10 anos, e de todo modo pode ter sido falha dos meus professores (ou o problema pode ter sido reclassificado nesse meio tempo, não sei). Quanto ao NP-completo, concordo com tudo. P.S. O link que você passou parece quebrado...

Comment: Não foi reclassificado não, é só que esse é um erro bem comum que as pessoas fazem mesmo... Quanto ao link, faltou um "www." no começo. ops.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Em um computador convencional, um determinado dado (i.e. um "bit") está sempre em um único estado - `0` ou `1`. Em um computador quântico, esse mesmo dado (chamado "qubit") pode estar em qualquer [**sobreposição**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobreposi%C3%A7%C3%A3o_qu%C3%A2ntica) desses dois estados, até o momento em que ele é medido (colapsando para um único valor). Isso ocorre segundo as leis da Mecânica Quântica, que inclui coisas como o [entrelaçamento](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entrela%C3%A7amento_qu%C3%A2ntico) (que é descrito como uma das bases da computação quântica, embora eu não saiba dizer qual é exatamente o papel dele).

O que torna um computador quântico mais rápido que um convencional é portanto a sua capacidade de progredir de um estado probabilístico para outro estado probabilístico sem a necessidade de enumerar todas as possibilidades envolvidas. Para entender isso, ajuda conhecer a classe de complexidade [BPP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPP):

## Bounded-error Probabilistic Polynomial time

Um problema é dito estar na BPP se existe um algoritmo para ele com as seguintes propriedades:

- Um componente aleatório (i.e. o algoritmo pode usar dados aleatórios ou tomar decisões aleatórias);
- Tempo de execução polinomial em relação ao tamanho da entrada, no pior caso;
- A resposta ("sim" ou "não") tem pelo menos 2/3 de chance de estar correta.

  - Estritamente falando, admitem-se respostas erradas, desde que a chance das mesmas seja inferior à das respostas certas (i.e. o valor 2/3 pode ser substituído por outro).

Todo problema em P está em BPP, entretanto há problemas em BPP que ainda não se sabe se está em P. O número desses problemas vêm diminuindo (ex.: até pouco tempo atrás, não existia algoritmo polinomial para se dizer se [um número é ou não primo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teste_de_primalidade_AKS), apenas [um algoritmo probabilístico](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teste_de_primalidade_de_Miller-Rabin)), o que leva à conjectura que `P = BPP`, mas ainda existem casos.

> Nota: além da classe BPP, há outras situações em que um algoritmo probabilístico é desejável. Por exemplo, não se pode garantidamente resolver um problema NP-Completo em tempo polinomial, mas poderia-se - em um busca exaustiva - empregar probabilidades para reduzir o espaço de busca. Em um computador convencional, isso não traz benefício algum entretanto...

OK, e como um algoritmo probabilístico funciona, já que existe uma grande possibilidade de erro? Simplesmente executando-o várias vezes de modo a reduzir a margem de erro. Se na primeira rodada há 1/3 de chance de erro, após a segunda há `(1/3)*(1/3) = 1/9`, após a terceira `1/27` e assim por diante. De modo que basta pegar os resultados de várias rodadas e verificar qual deles ocorre com mais frequência, e tomá-lo como o resultado certo.

## Combinações

Um único bit pode estar somente em dois estados, `0` ou `1`. Dois bits podem estar em quatro, `00`, `01`, `10` ou `11`, três bits em oito, e assim por diante. Isso significa que se você partiu do estado `100` e aplicou alguma operação probabilística, há 1 chance em 8 de se chegar a qualquer um dos estados seguintes. Após várias operações em sequência, o número de possibilidades aumenta enormemente. Isso significa que é necessário executar um número muito grande de rodadas para se chegar a um resultado com um nível aceitável de confiança.

No caso da computação quântica, por outro lado, a própria sobreposição de estados guarda em si as probabilidades a partir das quais se chegou a um determinado estado. Assim, partindo do estado `100` se chega ao estado `???` após a primeira operação, ao estado `???` após a segunda, e assim por diante, até que todas as operações sejam executadas. Somente no final, quando o resultado for lido (i.e. os qubits forem medidos) é que um conjunto de valores concretos - tipo `010` - será obtido.

Explicando de uma outra forma, se no computador convencional se partiu de `100` e chegou a `101`, a próxima etapa terá como base o estado `101`. Se a primeira etapa foi repetida 20 vezes e em 17 delas se chegou ao `101`, então a segunda etapa será executada 17 vezes com o estado `101` como base (e 3 vezes a partir de uma outra base). Digamos que a segunda etapa produziu `011` em 15 dessas repetições.

Já no computador quântico o resultado da primeira etapa será `???`, com 85% de chance de ser `101`, e o resultado da segunda etapa será `???`, com pelo menos 75% de chance de ser `011` (85% * 88,2%). Tudo isso numa única execução! Enquanto o computador convencional teria de executar um alto número de vezes para se chegar ao mesmo resultado com um nível de confiança similar (e mais tantas vezes para se reduzir a margem de erro a um valor aceitável - algo que ambos, convencional e quântico, têm de fazer de qualquer forma).

Respondendo então à pergunta, o que torna o computador quântico tão mais rápido é a possibilidade de, em uma única sequência de operações, se chegar ao mesmo resultado que um computador convencional chegaria se executasse um conjunto muito maior de operações.

É um caso similar ao das placas de aceleração gráfica, onde são realizadas operações envolvendo vetores, matrizes, etc diretamente nos circuitos do hardware, sendo que as mesmas operações para serem executadas na CPU demandaria um conjunto bem maior de operações sobre tipos de dados mais simples (i.e. números), envolvendo loops. Nesse caso a *escala* da otimização é bem maior, mas em princípio tudo o que um computador quântico faz poderia ser simulado em um computador convencional (a Máquina de Turing Quântica continua sendo teoricamente equivalente à Máquina de Turing).