# Como números primos são importantes na criptografia?

Tags: criptografia

De que forma números primos são uma parte importante em alguns sistemas de criptografia? Como funciona esse processo e em que parte entram os números primos?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Há dois tipos de criptografia: a **simétrica** (onde ambos os participantes compartilham um segredo) e a **assimétrica** (onde um tem um segredo que o outro não possui). A simétrica não faz uso de números primos, de um modo geral (ela é baseada na Probabilidade Discreta), enquanto a assimétrica faz uso extensivo dos mesmos (ela é baseada na Teoria dos Números, como [apontado por Alexandre Lara](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66523/215)). A razão disso é que enquanto a simétrica pode basear toda sua segurança no segredo compartilhado, a assimétrica não pode fazer isso, pois um dos lados da comunicação não tem acesso a esse segredo, e portanto não pode fazer operações com ele. É necessário buscar essa segurança em algum outro lugar.

Com frequência essa segurança é encontrada na **intratabilidade** de certos problemas da matemática. Um deles, como também já mencionado, é a dificuldade de se fatorar números grandes de forma eficiente. Outro é calcular o logaritmo discreto de um número qualquer módulo um número primo (ex.: se eu elevar `5` a `x` e fazer o resto da divisão por `7`, o resultado será `2`; quanto é `x`?). E esses problemas normalmente envolvem números primos, uma vez que vários teoremas estabelecem que a operação X é fácil/difícil/possível/impossível se seus operandos são primos.

Eu ainda conheço pouco sobre o assunto, mas vou dar dois exemplos bem simplificados que demonstram a importância dos primos na criptografia: o [Diffie-Hellman](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie-Hellman) e o [RSA](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA). No caso do Diffie-Hellman, o número primo usado no cálculo não precisa ser secreto, ele apenas provê as propriedades necessárias para o cálculo desejado ser possível. Já no RSA, os primos precisam ser escolhidos ao acaso e mantidos em sigilo.

## Diffie-Hellman

Digamos que Alice e Bob querem se comunicar de forma confidencial, usando criptografia simétrica, mas eles não possuem nenhum segredo em comum. Para simplificar, vamos dizer que sua preocupação é apenas com a confidencialidade da comunicação, não com sua integridade (i.e. eles receiam que alguém irá monitorar a comunicação, mas não [alterá-la](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7051/215)). Ambos conhecem um número primo `p` muito grande e um valor `g` entre `1` e `p-1`. Uma maneira de ambos "produzirem" um segredo compartilhado com o auxílio desses números é a seguinte:

Alice escolhe um número `a` qualquer e calcula o resto da divisão de `g` elevado a `a` por `p` (i.e. `A = g^a (mod p)`). Bob também escolhe um número `b` e calcula `B = g^b (mod p)`. Ambos trocam esses valores `A` e `B` entre si. Pelas leis da exponenciação, Alice pode calcular `B^a = (g^b)^a = g^(a*b) (mod p)`. Bob também pode calcular `A^b = (g^a)^b = g^(a*b) (mod p)`. Ou seja, ambos calcularam o mesmo valor, e esse valor pode ser usado como o segredo compartilhado necessário para usarem criptografia simétrica.

Ok, mas por que esse valor é um "segredo"? Bom, somente Alice conhece `a` e somente Bob conhece `b`. Um atacante que monitorasse a comunicação apenas veria `A` e `B`. Como calcular `g^(a*b) (mod p)` a partir desses valores? Bom, se `A = g^a` e o atacante conhece `A`, `g` e `p` então ele só tem que achar um `a` tal que `g^a = A (mod p)` e então fazer `B^a`, tal como Alice fez. Mas esse é justamente o logaritmo discreto mencionado anteriormente! Se o domínio fossem os números Reais, calcular o logaritmo de um número é trivial (`log_a(b) = ln(b)/ln(a)`), mas nos números discretos isso é bem mais difícil - pelo menos quando essa operação é feita módulo um número primo.

**Importância dos primos pro DH:** Lembra daquele parâmetro `g` escolhido anteriormente? Ocorre que todos os números que são primos com `p` podem ser "alcançados" a partir de alguma potência de `g`. Usando `5` e `7` como exemplos, temos que:

```
    1 = 5^0 = 1 (mod 7)
    5 = 5^1 = 5 (mod 7)
   25 = 5^2 = 4 (mod 7)
  125 = 5^3 = 6 (mod 7)
  625 = 5^4 = 2 (mod 7)
 3125 = 5^5 = 3 (mod 7)
15625 = 5^6 = 1 (mod 7) <-- começou a repetir; mas todos os nºs entre 1 e 6 já aparecerem
78125 = 5^7 = 5 (mod 7)
...
```

Mas se `7` é primo, então os "números primos com `7`" serão todos os números menores que `7` (exceto o zero, e com a adição do um). Se o módulo escolhido fosse `12`, por exemplo, teria bem menos resultados:

```
    1 = 5^0 = 1 (mod 12)
    5 = 5^1 = 5 (mod 12)
   25 = 5^2 = 1 (mod 12) <-- já?!
  125 = 5^3 = 5 (mod 12)
  625 = 5^4 = 1 (mod 12) <-- sigh... vamos tentar outro?

    1 = 7^0 = 1 (mod 12)
    7 = 7^1 = 7 (mod 12)
   49 = 7^2 = 1 (mod 12) <-- argh!

    1 = 3^0 = 1 (mod 12)
    3 = 3^1 = 3 (mod 12)
    9 = 3^2 = 9 (mod 12) <-- agora vai!
   27 = 3^3 = 3 (mod 12) <-- d'oh!

    1 = 9^0 = 1 (mod 12)
    9 = 9^1 = 9 (mod 12)
   81 = 9^2 = 9 (mod 12) <-- aí já é perseguição...
```

Nem todo número composto é tão "ruim" (acho), mas o fato é que se a partir de um gerador `g` só se pode chegar a um subconjunto pequeno dos números menores que `p`, então a chance de Alice e Bob escolherem um chave única e secreta diminui bastante (pois o adversário pode não conhecer `a` e `b`, mas ele vai acabar achando outro número `x` tal que `A = g^x` ou `B = g^x` com muito pouco esforço). Daí a importância de um número primo e grande pro protocolo (tem tantos `x`s que poderiam resultar em `g^x = A` que não dá pra testar todos).

## RSA

Digamos que você codifique (*encode*) um texto a ser transmitido de forma confidencial na forma de um número `M`. Você quer enviar esse texto pra mim, mas nós não compartilhamos nenhum segredo. Entretanto, eu conheço dois primos `p` e `q` bem grandes que ninguém mais conhece (i.e. ninguém sabe que eu *escolhi* esses dois dentre o mar de primos conhecidos), multipliquei os dois resultando em `m = p*q` e publiquei esse `m`, junto com um número `e` qualquer (esse `e` não precisa ser primo, mas precisa atender a certos requisitos simples). Você calcula então `C = M^e (mod m)` e envia `C` pra mim.

Bom, o que me interessa não é `C`, e sim `M`. E pro atacante, também só interessa `M`. Mas como fazer a operação inversa, calcular `M` a partir de `C`, `m` e `e`? Se fosse no contexto dos números Reais seria fácil: bastaria fazer a "raiz `e`-ésima de `C`". Só que quando você fez o resto da divisão de `M^e` por `m` você "jogou fora" a maior parte do número - `C` é pequeno, bem menor que `M^e`, e talvez nem seja um "quadrado perfeito" (metaforicamente falando). Não dá pra simplesmente calcular essa raiz, e mesmo que dê vamos acabar chegando num resultado diferente de `M`...

Felizmente, há um teorema que diz que se `m = p*q` então há um número `f = (p-1)*(q-1)` que pode me ajudar a calcular `M`: ocorre que o número `e` escolhido anteriormente possui um inverso módulo `f` que é fácil de calcular, e se eu tiver esse número - que chamarei de `d` - então basta eu fazer uma nova exponenciação para encontrar o resultado que eu estava buscando:

```
C = M^e (mod m)
M = C^d (mod m)
```

Como eu conheço os primos `p` e `q`, é fácil pra mim calcular `d`. Mas quem não conhece esses números, e não consegue fatorar `m` para descobri-los (pois `m` é um número muito grande) não possui as "ferramentas" necessárias para chegar ao mesmo resultado. Não dá pra testar todos os números `0 <= d < m` possíveis, e não tem nada que facilite esse cálculo sem o conhecimento dos primos envolvidos. De modo que enquanto "fatorar" for um problema difícil, decifrar `C` a partir das informações públicas apresentadas (`m` e `e`) também será difícil.

**Importância dos primos pro RSA:** se o número `m` for escolhido ao acaso, fatorá-lo não deve ser muito difícil - uma vez que é bastante provável que ele tenha muitos fatores pequenos. E sempre que um fator pequeno é encontrado, pode-se dividir `m` por esse fator e agora o problema da fatoração passa a ser aplicado a um número muito menor. No final, pode-se usar a força bruta para fatorar o que sobrar. E uma vez conhecidos os fatores primos, pode-se calcular a função `phi(m)` e com base nela achar o inverso `d` de `e` que permita decifrar os dados encriptados.

Usando um número que somente tem dois fatores primos, garante-se que o processo de fatoração será o mais difícil possível para quem não conhece os fatores, porém o esquema todo fácil para quem os conhece. Do contrário seria necessário usar números bem maiores, o que acabaria por tornar todo o processo difícil para ambos.

## Criptografia pós-quantum

Como já havia comentado na [sua pergunta anterior sobre computação quântica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44709/215), vários desses problemas que são intratáveis hoje se tornariam tratáveis caso fosse construído um computador quântico com capacidade suficiente. A segurança do RSA estaria totalmente quebrada (pois o [Algoritmo de Shor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) permitiria fatorar semiprimos grandes em tempo polinomial) e a do Diffie-Hellman também (tanto o "clássico" - esse que descrevi na resposta - quanto o das [Curvas Elípticas](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criptografia_de_curva_el%C3%ADptica) - que é essencialmente equivalente mas muito mais eficiente - pois o mesmo algoritmo também permite calcular o logaritmo discreto em tempo polinomial).

A [criptografia baseada em retículos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice-based_cryptography) (ou seriam "reticulados"?) é considerada resistente à computação quântica, mas não sei te dizer se ela é baseada em alguma propriedade dos números primos ou não. De todo modo, citei aqui para frisar que o que confere segurança à criptografia assimétrica são os problemas intratáveis, de modo que a importância dos números primos hoje se dá pela quantidade de problemas em aberto envolvendo esse tipo de número. E dada a dificuldade de se construir computadores quânticos eficientes, é provável que essa importância se mantenha ainda por um bom tempo.

Comment: Falou em criptografia, você aparece. +1 pela resposta e pelo excelente trabalho que vem trazendo a essa comunidade.

Comment: *aplausos* .... antes não sabia muito bem sobre criptografia, mas esse pequeno texto me mostrou o que 3 páginas tentaram me explicar.

Comment: Creio que os algoritmos mais modernos não estão usando mais o conceito da fatoração única e com isto números primos perdem a importância neste aspecto.

Comment: @Motta Desculpe, não entendi. Existem algoritmos de tudo quanto é tipo, e de fato nem todos eles se baseiam em números primos. Em particular o ECC (curvas elípticas), principal "substituto" do RSA hoje em dia, não se baseia em fatoração, mas não sei dizer se usa números primos ou não (meu conhecimento de criptografia ainda é bastante limitado).

Comment: @mgibsonbr o meu também mas creio que grandes números primos não são mais usados nestes novos.   https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_esponja

Answer (score 16):

A primeira coisa que você deve ter em mente é que a criptografia é uma área extremamente relacionada a Teoria dos Números.

Existe um conceito em Teoria dos Números chamado Fatoração de Inteiros, em que afirma que todo número composto (aqueles não são primos) pode ser representado em fatores primos.

Se você pegar 2 números primos grandes e multiplicá-los, você irá obter um número inteiro (não-primo) muito grande.

As aplicações disso em criptografia está na dificuldade e tempo que se leva para fatorar um número inteiro muito grande em fatores primos. Isto ocorre porque não há fórmula mágica, você tem que testar todas as combinações de números até pelo menos a raiz quadrada do número que você quer obter. Exemplo, digamos que temos o número 36:

36 / 2 = 18

18 / 2 = 9

9 / 3 = 3

3 / 3 = 1

Eu fatorei o número 36 em 2 * 2 * 3 * 3, onde 2 e 3 são fatores primos.

A criptografia RSA, por exemplo, é bastante dependente desse conceito de fatorização em fatores primos. Resumindo esse tipo de criptografia: A chave pública consiste da multiplicação de dois números primos grandes, enquanto que a nossa chave privada consiste justamente dos números primos utilizados.

Certo, mas qual a vantagem disso?

Um algoritmo de criptografia não necessariamente significa que o objetivo dele é ser inquebrável. Em teoria, por exemplo, por força bruta é possível quebrar quase todos (ou talvez, todos) os algoritmos de criptografia existentes. Um bom algoritmo de criptografia tem o objetivo de garantir que a informação permanecerá segura por tempo suficiente até que seu valor não tenha utilidade nenhuma pra uma pessoa mal intencionada .

No caso da RSA, os usuários podem utilizar a chave pública (consistindo do produto de números primos grandes) para criptografar a informação, enquanto você utilizará a sua chave privada (os números primos utilizados na multiplicação) para  descriptografar. Qualquer outra pessoa que deseje obter essa informação terá que fatorar o número, e isso levaria uma quantidade de tempo gigantesca.

Você pode ler mais no Wikipedia sobre o [algoritmo de criptografia RSA](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA).

Answer (score 1):

Porque a teoria baseia-se na dificuldade em se fatorar número primo, diga-se extremamente longos números primos, com centenas de dígitos.

Criptografia é uma ciência baseada na teoria dos números. E os inteiros podem ser decompostos em números primos (exceção de 0 e 1).

Muitos algoritmos ([RSA](http://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) por exemplo) são criados com base nessa dificuldade em se fatorar números primos.

Comment: Fatorar números primos é fácil: os fatores são `1` e o próprio primo! :) O que é difícil é fatorar [**semiprimos**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_semiprimo) - números compostos por exatamente dois fatores primos, e cada um deles bem grande.

Answer (score 1):

Os números primos têm importância não só em criptografia mas em inúmeros outros tópicos da ciência da computação, pelo fato de um número primo poder formar um "campo de Galois".

Por exemplo, um campo baseado no número 7 e com gerador 2 (mas qualquer número entre 2 e 6 serviria como gerador):

```
2 * 0 -> 0
2 * 1 -> 2
2 * 2 -> 4
2 * 3 -> 6
2 * 4 -> 1 (resto da divisão de 8 por 7, ou mod 7)
2 * 5 -> 3 (mod 7)
2 * 6 -> 5
2 * 7 -> 0
2 * 8 -> 2
...
```

Ou seja, multiplicando o gerador por "n" vezes, podemos obter qualquer valor do campo, que vai de 0 a 6 (7 elementos).

Supondo que você tem uma mensagem composta unicamente de números entre 0 e 6, um algoritmo de criptografia simplíssimo poderia ser criado com base nessa propridade: criptografar multiplicando por 4, e decriptar multiplicando novamente por 2. Como 4x2=8, e o resto da divisão de 8 por 7 é 1, encriptar e decriptar em seguida tem o efeito líquido de multiplicar por 1, que é a mensagem original, então fica "provado" que a mensagem original é recuperável.

Um "campo" baseado num número não-primo não é um campo, mas sim um anel, porque nem todo número abaixo do tamanho (ou ordem) do anel pode ser um gerador. Num anel de 12 elementos, 5 poderia ser um gerador (porque 5 não tem nenhum fator em comum com 12), mas 2 não pode, 3 não pode, 4 não pode, 6 não pode...

Agora, se "gerarmos" os números de outra forma, usando exponenciação, por exemplo com gerador 2 e campo 7:

```
2 ** 0 -> 1
2 ** 1 -> 2
2 ** 2 -> 4
2 ** 3 -> 1 (mod 7)
2 ** 4 -> 2 (mod 7)
....
```

vemos que o gerador 2 não é mais adequado, porque ele começa a repetir resultados muito cedo. Ele gera apenas valores 1, 2 e 4 repetidamente. Para um campo 7, apenas os geradores 3 e 5 servem (se a operação geradora for exponenciação):

```
3 ** 0 -> 1
3 ** 1 -> 3
3 ** 2 -> 9 mod 7 = 2
3 ** 3 -> 6 (mod 7)
3 ** 4 -> 4 
3 ** 5 -> 5
3 ** 6 -> 1
3 ** 7 -> 3
...
```

Note que o número 0 não pode ser gerado, então o período dos números gerados é sempre uma unidade menor que o campo. Se tivermos de criptografar uma mensagem com 6 "caracteres", o campo 7 é adequado.

O caso é: num anel cujo número de elementos não é primo (tipo 8, 9, 10, 12 elementos) NÃO EXISTE GERADOR que funcione com exponenciação. A sequência gerada começa a repetir-se muito rapidamente, apresentando apenas 2 ou 3 valores diferentes, ou mesmo degradando para uma sequencia de zeros.

Para fazer uma criptografia baseada em exponenciação, veja a outra resposta que explica a criptografia RSA, que funciona basicamente 
dessa forma: escolher um gerador e dois expoentes que se "anulam" mutuamente.