# Criar minha própria criptografia em PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber qual a lógica de um algorítimo para criptografar e descriptografar usando **PHP**.

Como criar a minha própria criptografia?

`Ex. |Stack| -> |AlbNU|`

- Como fazer isso?
- É possível ?

Comment: Só não pode contar o 'segredo' ;) Relaciondas: [Como funciona o algoritmo de criptografia AES?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43492/91) e [Como números primos são importantes na criptografia?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66513/91)

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=como+funciona+criptografia

Comment: Existem um monte de formas de fazer criptografia. Umas boas, outras ruins. Todo dia alguém inventa uma forma ruim. Formas boas tem que ter um fundamento matemático bem forte para funcionar.

Comment: @rray & Bacco. Sei que é uma pergunta ampla e há diversos websites contendo informações sobre criptografia. Más recorri ao Stack. Pois junto a vocês eu gostaria de saber **como criar uma simples** e acredito que ajudará muitas pessoas!

Comment: Vai ajudar muitas pessoas a fazer besteira, uma das regras básicas para criptografia é não inventar uma. (mas isso é só uma observação, o voto de ampla não tem a ver com isso, e sim o fato de que tem que ser mais específico, senão não dá pra responder - a começar pelo que você entende por criptografia, e qual objetivo a ser atingido).

Comment: @Bacco com o 'Ajudará muitas pessoas' eu quis dizer que muitos tem está duvida e vontade de criar sua própia criptografia apenas para estudo e testes! não que iram fazer a criptografia e jogar em um sistema de cadastro de clientes!

Comment: Minha sugestão é você dar uma pesquisada nas perguntas já existentes, como o link de pesquisa acima, e nesse post aqui (veja as várias respostas): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/70 - aí, com os conceitos que obtiver, vai poder [edit] sua pergunta e deixar ela mais legal. Aí sim acho que vai ser de maior ajuda, e obter respostas úteis. O problema é que como está, são possíveis muitas respostas abrangendo muitos ângulos diferentes sobre o assunto, que é extenso, e nenhuma servir para o seu objetivo.

Comment: Eu quis explicar o fundamento com um código simples, mas tem gente que fica negativando... Então só lamento...

Comment: // Imagine que você tem todos os caracteres aqui A, B, C ..., a, b, c ...
$cifraoriginal = array("S","t","a","c","k");

// E aqui você tem letras correspondentes que irá trocar
$trocaletras    = array("A","l","b","N","U");

$palavra = "|Stack|";

$palavra_modificada = str_replace( $cifraoriginal,  $trocaletras, $palavra );

echo $palavra_modificada;

Agora imagine que vc quer que toda vez que tiver uma sequência "de", seja substituída por "K", daí vc faz outro replace, e por aí vai.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandreAlonsodeSi Acho que tem uma dessas de cifra em alguma resposta, se eu achar o link, colo aqui nos comentários como complemento. PS: O negativo não foi meu, mas entre cifra e criptografia da forma que é entendido em TI, tem um abismo enorme. Para fins gerais uma cifra é uma forma de criptografia, mas isso como noção acadêmica. Acho legal deixar isso bem claro quando responder algo assim, para que o leitor possa entender o contexto.

Comment: @Bacco Eu até tinha posto um comentário mas apaguei porque não dava pra pôr a explicação junto por limite de caracteres no comentário.
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifra_de_substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: Qualquer coisa que você faça com algum conteúdo, que o torne ilegível, e que você consiga desfazer depois, é criptografia. Então é difícil responder essa tua pergunta.