# Como será a nova lógica de programação de computadores quânticos?

Tags: algoritmo, compilação, binary, ciência-da-computação, teoria-da-computação

Fala-se muito em computadores quânticos com alta performance e capacidade de processamento. Diferentemente dos *bits*, os *qubits* dos computadores quânticos, trabalham com superposição, podem assumir três valores distintos: 0 ou 1 ou 0 e 1 simultaneamente.

Sei que é uma pergunta extensa, mas gostaria apenas de um explicação básica sobre o assunto. Já que li algo a respeito, no entanto, por ser um tema complexo, não ficou claro.

Como será a nova lógica de programação desses computadores?

Os códigos clássicos serão re-aproveitados?

Comment: Eu ACHO que os códigos que já fizemos vão continuar funcionando OK, mas terão novas atualizações de framework que podem rodar mais rápido.

Comment: Pelo que entendi somente problemas do tipo NP (https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_%28complexidade%29) seriam mais eficientes em CQ , problemas comuns continuariam se servindo do que temos hoje.

Comment: A pergunta e a resposta (até agora) são **sintomáticas** que o site continua atraindo profissionais de alto gabarito. Obrigado aos dois!

Comment: Relacionado: ["Quais as principais diferenças entre um computador quântico e um computador convencional?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44709/215)

Comment: Acredito que a mudança virá com a adoção de computadores neurais, usando o conceito [memristor](http://www8.hp.com/h30458/br/ptb/smb/Curso-r%C3%A1pido-O-Memristor_1444588.html), A HP já está criando memórias usando esta tecnologia e o futuro é promissor.

Comment: Para quem quiser se aventurar nesta area, há alguns links bem interessantes fornecidos abaixo:
[Google - Quantum Computing Playground](http://www.quantumplayground.net/#/home) e
[IBM - Quantum Experience](http://www.research.ibm.com/quantum/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A diferença não se dará (ao menos por um considerável espaço de tempo) na codificação de nós mortais programadores.

Como vivemos num mundo físico e não quântico, nossas aplicações são feitas na maioria das vezes para solucionar problemas físicos. Atualmente usamos computação baseada em bits, e cada bit só pode ter um estado físico (0|1), chamado estado clássico. Aprendemos a transformar esses bits em elementos representáveis com significados humano como números.

A computação quântica muda radicalmente esse conceito, pois como um qubit está em estado quântico e existe infinitos estados quânticos, não há como representar esses estados no modelo clássico sem fazer uma *medição*. 
Quem já leu ou estudou mecânica quântica sabe que ao realizar tal medida altera-se o estado para o valor mensurado com uma margem de probabilidade de outros estados. É sobre essa margem que a computação quântica trabalha e é neles que serão utilizados os algoritmos.

Com isso em mente, sabemos que computadores que trabalham com estados clássicos continuarão sendo eficientes para operações de comparação e soma.

Já para operações probabilísticas a computação quântica será a chave. 
Um exemplo prático disso é a previsão do tempo. Os algoritmos atuais (chamados de modelos matemáticos) fazem cálculos probabilísticos usando o conceito de rede neural, dividindo em passos e calculando a probabilidade de cada passo, sempre optando pelo mais provável. Para saber outros resultados do modelo, é necessário alterar os valores iniciais indicando qual caminho deseja seguir.
No modelo quântico isso se daria simultaneamente, ou seja, todas (supondo que exista qubits suficientes) as probabilidades seriam calculadas ao mesmo tempo.

Só com isso em mente eu acredito que não mudaremos radicalmente a forma de programar e sim como obteremos os resultados, a menos que nossa matemática mude (evolua) a ponto de precisarmos de novos conceitos de pensamento em código.

Para aqueles que estão lendo isso sem saber nada sobre o assunto, já existe um computador quântico comercial chamado [D-Wave](http://www.dwavesys.com/) e assim como foi com os computadores no inicio da era da informática, ele está sendo mais usado para fins científicos do que comerciais, mas em breve isso pode mudar.

Para saber mais sobre computação quântica indico [essa leitura](http://www.sbmac.org.br/boletim/pdf_2004/livro_08_2004.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

A lógica de um computador quântico é completamente diferente!

Primeiro, toda função usada em um computador quântico deve ser reversível, ou seja, com a saída deve ser possível gerar novamente a entrada. A maioria dos algoritmos dos computadores convencionais já quebram essa regra. Por exemplo a adição não é reversível! Se você somar 2+7 vai dar 9, mas é impossível fazer uma função que pegue 9 e retorne 2 + 7, pois um pouco da informação foi perdida no processo.

Assim as operações de adição, subtração, multiplicação e divisão convencionais não são possíveis em um computador quântico. Com essa restrição também se chega que qualquer função quântica deve ter o mesmo número de bits de entrada e de bits de saída. Isso não é uma limitação, pois métodos reversíveis existem para todos as funções computáveis, porém requer uma maneira diferente de pensar na resolução de um problema.

Outra propriedade bem diferente é que, no meio de um programa quântico nenhum bit pode ser modificado, copiado ou deletado. Uma operação deste tipo iria "estragar" os bits! Além disso, em uma função quântica não podem existir loops, nem ifs, nem nenhum tipo de controle convencional de fluxo: uma operação é executada depois da outra de forma sequencial. E as operações quânticas alteram todos os bits de uma vez de uma forma que seriam necessárias muitas operações normais para faze-lo, formando um novo conjunto de instruções básicas que é muito mais eficiente para alguns tipos de problemas.

Se o computador quântico começar a ser viável, a ideia mais aceita é que a programação continuará da mesma forma, porém com funções quânticas! Um computador convencional vai escrever os bits de entrada na memória de um computador quântico e dar um sinal para ele iniciar a função. Depois que o resultado está calculado é só ler os valores de saída. Imagino que vá existir uma biblioteca de funções quânticas para se usar no código e isso deve ficar transparente para o programador.

O computador quântico é extremamente rápido para se fazer uma transformada discreta de Fourier resolvendo ela com complexidade O(n^2). Em um computador convencional essa operação tem complexidade O(n*2^n), muito maior. Daí, em 1994 um matemático chamado Peter Shor fez um algoritmo quântico com complexidade O(n^3) para fatorar um número utilizando a transformada quântica de Fourier. Depois disso o interesse nos computadores quânticos cresceu muito, pois fatorar um número com essa velocidade conseguiria quebrar muitos dos sistemas de criptografia atuais.

Tentei falar o mais importante, é muito difícil explicar isso tentando ser o mais básico possível! Uma discussão mais detalhada pode facilmente chegar em filosofia existencial profunda e na estranheza do universo, o que não iria ajudar muito a responder a pergunta :)