# O que é um algoritmo determinístico e não determinístico?

Tags: algoritmo, terminologia, ciência-da-computação

O que é um Algoritmo determinístico e não determinístico?

- Quais as características de ambos?
- É possível implementar ambos em qualquer linguagem?

> OBS: se possível exemplifique com alguma implementação

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Algoritmo determinístico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_determin%C3%ADstico) é o que sempre produz o mesmo resultado dadas determinadas entradas de dados.

A maioria dos algoritmos são determinísticos. Ainda bem :)

Por isso nem sempre os algoritmos reproduzem bem os problemas do mundo, os problemas reais costumam ser indeterminísticos, qualquer tentativa de reproduzir o mundo real beira a insanidade. É possível fazer uma representação simplificada do problema real. Daí a definição de OOP como sendo uma ferramenta para reproduzir o mundo real é fundamentalmente errada.

[Algoritmo não determinístico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_n%C3%A3o_determin%C3%ADstico) é aquele que pode produzir resultados diferentes mesmo com os mesmos dados entrados.

Isto é comum porque todo algoritmo que depende de dados externos, como o tempo, concorrência ou falha de hardware por exemplo, possivelmente ou certamente produzirá um resultado diferente.

Os exemplos mais óbvios são os que pegam o horário do computador no momento da execução, os que **usam** geradores de números aleatórios, os que possuem características inerentemente probabilísticas.

Mas há casos menos óbvios, como os que dependem de dados que não podem ser bem classificados. Como o próprio nome diz, quando não é possível determinar o que fazer o resultado pode ser diferente. Um algoritmo de classificação que executa em um *roll* de dados que possuem duplicidades exatas devem classificá-los como? Existe uma forma de determinar isto? Existem algoritmos que não conseguem.

Um algoritmo que lê arquivos, redes ou outras formas (em baixo nível) são indeterminísticos, não se sabe o que virá desta leitura, já o que será feito com os dados lidos (nível mais alto) possivelmente serão determinísticos, já que eles passam ser uma entrada de novos algoritmos. Estes algoritmos não sabem o que vão encontrar lá, são dados externos, eles podem ter sido modificados por outras fontes. Então olhando em um nível mais alto o algoritmo de leitura será determinístico.

O *tracing garbage collector* é um dos mais famosos indeterminismos da computação. Por mais que as regras sejam bem estabelecidas, não se sabe quando ele será disparado, não se sabe quando o algoritmo produzirá um resultado que o dispare. Depende de muitos fatores, alguns deles que não estão sob controle da aplicação.

Note que indeterminismo não é o mesmo que aleatório. Não quer dizer que necessariamente acontecerá qualquer coisa, apenas que ela não pode ser determinada antecipadamente.

Sim, é possível implementá-los em qualquer linguagens. Algumas poucas evitam, ou pelo menos tentam isolar, o uso dos indeterminísticos. Mas não tem como fugir deles na maioria dos problemas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não entendi bem a parte de leitura de arquivo ou rede. Se o mesmo algoritmo lê a mesma cadeia de bytes mais de uma vez (o mesmo arquivo, ou dados iguais trafegados na rede), por que ele seria não-determinístico?

Comment: Melhorou agora?

Comment: Haskell trata isso de uma maneira excelente.

Comment: É, [Monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)).

Comment: Não melhorou muito... O exemplo da leitura de dados externos continua trazendo alguma confusão. Se o algoritmo processa o conteúdo do arquivo e o arquivo for o mesmo, as saídas serão as mesmas - o algoritmo é determinístico. Se o arquivo mudar, então as entradas do algoritmo mudaram - mas o algoritmo continua determinístico.

Comment: @Caffé concordo que o algoritmo de mais alto nível é determinístico mas o de baixo nível não. Ele manda ler uma posição do disco ou manda ler o que está no *buffer* da rede, a entrada de dados é o pedido de leitura de algo, não são os dados. Pediu para ser **algo**, veio uma coisa, depois pediu de novo, esse algo é o mesmo (mesma posição do disco ou *buffer*, por exemplo), vem outra coisa diferente, porque o que está lá não é de controle daquele algoritmo. Isto é indeterminístico. É dado externo que não pode ser garantido. Acho que o problema aí é a interpretação do que é a entrada de dados.

Comment: @bigown Também achei essa definição um pouco ampla demais. E um *gerador* de números pseudo-aleatórios, é determinístico ou não? Cada vez que você chama, dá uma saída diferente, e sem entrada nenhuma... Mas eu chamaria sim um PRNG de determinístico, pois sua saída é determinada pelo seu **estado** interno. Da mesma forma, a função que lê de um arquivo depende sim do seu estado (ou, se recebe um stream, do estado do stream, pra qual byte do arquivo ele "aponta"), mas isso não torna ele indeterminístico. Isso tudo é só minha opinião, contudo, traçar uma linha que separa os dois é complicado...

Comment: @mgibsonbr Tentei melhorar. O gerador pode ser determinístico, mas o seu uso pode não ser. O *stream* já é algo intermediário, já é algo que tem como entrada os dados que estavam presentes em algum lugar, aí é determinístico mesmo. Tudo depende do que é a entrada de dados. A confusão toda está aí. Esse é o meu entendimento. Concordo que traçar a linha não é tão simples.

Comment: Com o seu penúltimo comentário, entendi o que você quis dizer. O que está no comentário (o que é a entrada) está mais claro que na resposta.

Answer (score 16):

Um algoritmo determinístico é aquele que se comporta da mesma maneira em diferentes execuções, dadas as mesmas entradas e o mesmo estado interno da máquina (se relevante). Um não determinístico seria aquele que pode se comportar de forma diferente na mesma situação.

Os computadores são determinísticos. Salvo alguma falha no hardware (que introduzisse um bug no programa), qualquer implementação de qualquer algoritmo num computador clássico (não quântico) será determinística, ainda que sua saída ou seu comportamento pareça "caótico" aos nossos olhos. É até possível provar que [uma Máquina de Turing não determinística é equivalente a uma determinística](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_de_Turing_n%C3%A3o_determin%C3%ADstica#Equival.C3.AAncia_com_uma_M.C3.A1quina_de_Turing_Determin.C3.ADstica) (ou seja, todo algoritmo não determinístico poderia ser expresso - e portanto implementado - como um algoritmo determinístico).

Por essa razão, é difícil traçar uma linha que separe o determinístico do não determinístico. Um critério comum para diferenciá-los é se eles dependem de algum fator **aleatório** na sua execução - ainda que na prática esse fator seja dado por meio de um gerador de números pseudo-aleatórios (portanto determinístico) e/ou alguma entrada externa. Pois mesmo que o algoritmo use uma abordagem diferente (ex.: simular todos os caminhos de execução possíveis) na hora de *escolher* um ele vai precisar de algum critério para tal.

> Quais as características de ambos ?

A principal característica do não-determinístico é que não se pode prever seu tempo de execução, consumo de memória, etc, mesmo conhecidas as entradas [que não o fator aleatório]. Muitas vezes é difícil fazer isso *analiticamente* também para os determinísticos, mas ao menos duas execuções com as mesmas entradas resultarão sempre no mesmo comportamento.

> É possível implementar ambos em qualquer linguagem ?

Sim, pois como já mencionado, é possível simular uma Máquina de Turing não determinística em uma determinística. Se uma linguagem for Turing completa, então ela pode implementar qualquer algoritmo não determinístico.

> se possível exemplifique com alguma implementação

Um exemplo clássico é o quicksort com pivô aleatório: escolhe-se um elemento qualquer da lista, passa-se todos os elementos menores que ele pra trás, e todos os maiores pra frente. Então chama-se o algoritmo recursivamente na primeira e na segunda parte, até que uma delas contenha somente zero ou um elemento.

(Note que, na ausência de elementos duplicados, a **saída** do algoritmo é sempre a mesma, fator aleatório ou não; só o **comportamento** dele é que muda - quantos passos foram necessários para se chegar à mesma saída)

Contraste o quicksort com pivô arbitrário, que comumente é o elemento central da lista, ou o primeiro, ou um 1/3 ou 2/3 do caminho.

Há ainda casos que não se conhece um algoritmo determinístico eficiente para executar determinada função, mas um não determinístico sim. Como comentei na [pergunta sobre computação quântica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44709/215), um caso famoso é o "teste de primalidade", que recebe um número e afirma com X% de certeza se ele é ou não primo (i.e. há `1-X`% de chance dele classificar um número composto como "primo"). Hoje já se conhece um algoritmo polinomial determinístico para determinar se um número é primo, mas ainda existem outros problemas sem solução.

A classe de problemas que podem ser solucionados por um algoritmo probabilístico é a [BPP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPP) ("probabilístico de tempo polinomial comprometido à erros"), e conjectura-se que `BPP = P`. E, naturalmente, como para se implementar qualquer algoritmo probabilístico num computador determinístico é necessário um fator aleatório externo, essas implementações poderiam ser chamadas de não determinísticas.