# Como implementar memoização em uma função PHP?

Tags: php, funções, design-pattern

Vi hoje numa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103915) o seguinte código:

```
function fibonacci($n) {
    $a = 0;
    $b = 1;
    $c = 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i < $n ; $i++) { 
        $c = $a + $b;
        $a = $b;
        $b = $c;
    }
    return $c;
}
echo fibonacci(100) ."\n";
```

Essa função tem um problema de performance, pois a cada chamada recalcula toda a sequência de Fibonacci até o número passado. Sei resolver esse problema em outras linguagens usando [memoização](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_etimologias_de_termos_usados_em_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o#M)<sup>[detalhes em en](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)</sup> – uma espécie de cache interno da função. É possível fazer o mesmo em PHP? Como?

Comment: Teria como explicar resumidamente o que é memoização?

Comment: @rray Defini muito brevemente, as respostas podem explicar mais :)

Comment: Já ajudou um pouco, da pra twitar essa explicação :D

Comment: +1 pela pergunta, e dois comentários: 1) essa função não tem chamadas recursivas, então não se beneficiaria da memoização; 2) essa implementação é razoavelmente boa para calcular um único elemento da sequência (linear com a entrada), apenas se forem calculados vários é que há desperdício de processamento (i.e. sem ver a pergunta linkada isso não está claro).

Comment: Encontrei um artigo interessante a respeito do assunto: http://eddmann.com/posts/implementing-and-using-memoization-in-php/

Comment: @mgibsonbr Putz, burrice minha não ver que essa função não era recursiva. Ouvi "fibonacci" e imediatamente vieram à cabeça as ideias de recursão e memoização. E saí perguntando sem ter lido o código com atenção :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

É possível fazer um cache do dado, que é o princípio básico da memoização, algo assim:

```
function fibonacci($n) {
    static $cache = array();
    if (isset($cache[$n])) return $cache[$n];
    $a = 0;
    $b = 1;
    $c = 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i < $n ; $i++) { 
        $c = $a + $b;
        $a = $b;
        $b = $c;
    }
    $cache[$n] = $c;
    return $c;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/noL5sm). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uqaiqvks-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Function/Memoization.php).

A [variável local estática](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) foi usada para manter o estado entre as chamadas da função. Enquanto o código estiver sendo executado ela mantém seu valor. Ela funciona de forma semelhante à uma variável global, ou seja, [seu tempo de vida é global. Mas seu escopo é local](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101).

Esta solução é simplificada e ingênua, não tem nenhum tipo de persistência e não escala bem. Teria que fazer algo bem mais elaborado para atender outras demandas não tão triviais. Mas resolve legal para a maioria.

Se a preocupação é performance, neste tipo de algoritmo, é interessante pré-calcular uma sequência grande de números mais prováveis de uso e alocar no *array* já no código. Claro que poderá ter um consumo maior de memória. Até certo ponto compensa.

Esta técnica não funciona em todo tipo de algoritmo, especialmente em [algoritmos não determinísticos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102597/101), o que não é o caso presente.

Mas tem um jeito de já dar uma boa melhorada sem pré-calcular em tempo de desenvolvimento, ainda que vá consumir mais memória sem, potencialmente, precisar de todos os valores.

```
function fibonacci($n) {
    static $cache = array();
    static $prox = 3;
    $cache[0] = 0;
    $cache[1] = 1;
    $cache[2] = 1;
    if ($n < $prox) {
        echo "cache -> "; //está aqui só para mostrar que entrou aqui
        return $cache[$n];
    }
    for ($i = $prox; $i <= $n; $i++) $cache[$i] = $cache[$i - 1] + $cache[$i - 2];
    echo $i - $prox . " passos -> "; //está aqui só para mostrar que entrou aqui
    $prox = $n + 1;
    return $cache[$n];
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/geBVJQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wpxjssim-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Function/Memoization2.php).

Se quiser otimizar em tempo de desenvolvimento, pode adicionar `$cache[3] = 2;`, `$cache[3] = 3;`, `$cache[4] = 5;`, etc. O ganho será pequeno.

Se sabe que vai usar em uma sequência grande e sabe o maior valor (mesmo aproximado) pode ajudar mandando executar este número maior, assim popula o cache.

A [resposta que originou esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103915) agora tem uma variação de cálculo que não precisa passar por toda sequência. O que diminui a necessidade do cache.

Tem um [módulo para ajudar](https://github.com/arraypad/php-memoize) fazer cache de forma mais intensiva. Provavelmente pensaram em muita coisa que pode acontecer nessa situação e testaram bem. Mas pode ser um canhão pra matar passarinho.

Achei esta [outra solução](https://gist.github.com/mtdowling/4516558).

Particularmente prefiro a solução usando laço porque ela é mais natural em sequencia de dados. Recursão é para árvores e assemelhados.

Comment: Nesse caso eu diria:  Guardar o valor de retorno da função na variável seria mais viável. +1

Comment: A outra solução que você citou é similar à solução em JS, com closures. Mas prefiro o seu código com variável estática, fica mais simples. Eu sempre me esqueço que existe esse tipo de variável no PHP, pode ser mesmo uma mão na roda!

Comment: É solução de programador pragmático ao invés de acadêmico. Assim como este algoritmo ser um *loop* ao invés de recursivo :P