# Código recursivo C++

Tags: c++, recursão

Tenho a seguinte função iterativa:

```
int getNumPastasColididas(int i){
    int c = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        c += table[i].hasColided;
    return c; // c = 89832
}
```

Tentei reproduzir o funcionamento utilizando um código recursivo mas quando efetuo a chamada passando 0 como parâmetro ele não funciona, retornando 1.

```
int getNumPastasColididas(int i){
    return (i < size) ?: table[i].hasColided + getNumPastasColididas(i + 1);
}
```

Porque o código recursivo não reproduz o resultado do iterativo? Onde está o erro?

Comment: Ponha a função inteira pra facilitar pra gente.

Comment: A resposta te ajudou?

Comment: Alguma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não sabe como fazê-lo. Assim ajuda a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Os dois códigos não fazem a mesma coisa. Onde foi parar a variável `c`? Além disso ele encerrava antes da hora porque a condição está invertida.

```
int getNumPastasColididas(int i, int c) {
    return (i < size) ? table[i].hasColided + getNumPastasColididas(i + 1, c) : c;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Li0Rau). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yftigquo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/RecursiveTable.cpp).

Tive que simular o que está fazendo. Nas próximas pergunta faça um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Dito isto, [evite a recursão em casos assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101). Veja [Quando usar recursão e quando usar laços?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101) (atenção que complicada não significa grande, na verdade a simples costuma ser maior). Nesse caso teve que expor detalhe de implementação, o que não é ideal. Recursão é o mecanismo errado para este problema.

Answer (score 2):

Não é necessária a variável `c` como nosso colega sugeriu. O problema com seu código está na base da recursão e na condição do operador ternário. Quando a condição `i < size` é verdadeira (lado esquerdo do divisor `:`), a recursão deve continuar. Quando a condição for falsa, a recursão deve parar **retornando zero**.

Logo, sua função recursiva deve ser algo assim:

```
int getNumPastasColididas(int i){
    return (i < size) ? table[i].hasColided + getNumPastasColididas(i + 1) : 0;
}
```