# O que é um método recursivo?

Tags: c, terminologia, loop, recursão

A variável `resultado` dentro do `for` é recursiva?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int N,i;
double resultado=0.0;

scanf("%d",&N);

for (i=0; i<N; i++)
  {
   resultado= 1.0 / (resultado+2); 
  }

  printf("%0.10lf\n",1.0+resultado);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Quando usar recursão e quando usar laços?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21551/quando-usar-recurs%c3%a3o-e-quando-usar-la%c3%a7os)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em C temos funções e não métodos. Variáveis não são recursivas, porque para haver recursão precisa de uma ação e [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é estado.

Em geral ele pode ser usando no lugar de um laço de repetição. Na maioria das vezes não deveria. Deixe a recursão para casos onde ela seja mais intuitiva. Sequências normais funcionam melhor em laços. É possível transformar este laço em função recursiva, mas não faça sem um motivo para fazê-lo.

Tome cuidado para fazer uma função recursiva, ou seja, uma função que chame ela mesma, de forma incondicional. Quando faz isso ela vai ao infinito e nunca volta ao início. E se tiver estado nela ocorrerá este site aqui, ou a [*stack overflow*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101), o que quebrará a aplicação por exaustão de memória que vai sendo ocupada na [pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) sem que seja liberado em qualquer momento.

Recursão é a repetição de algo. Isto é recursão:

[image: Triângulos formados por triângulos]

Em programação é chamar uma rotina dentro dela mesma.

Tem algumas perguntas no site sobre o tema:

- [O que é uma recursão de cauda?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184494/101)
- [Quando usar recursão e quando usar laços?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101)
- [Qual é a vantagem de usarmos funções recursivas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101)
- [Código recursivo C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138497/101)
- [Dificuldade na Sintaxe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34200/101)
- [Recursividade números pares em C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286773/101)

Para entender recursão é preciso entender recursão! Entendeu?

[image: Livro com índice na página de recursão indica para a própria página]

Mais um exemplo típico:

[image: Recursão em vídeo]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).