# Exceção sem tratamento: System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#

Meu projeto *Winforms C#* possui uma rotina que retorna aproximadamente 6000 itens. Toda vez ao executar a rotina é exibido no `Connection.Open()` do `DataSet` a `StackOverflowException`. Nunca vi este erro. O que pode ocasiona-lo?

Comment: Ou a pergunta não está clara no que quer ou já está respondida em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101 com complemento em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/323954/101.

Comment: acredito que esse seja seu caso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290694/sqlconnection-open-returns-a-stackoverflow-exception

Answer (score 0):

`System.StackOverflowException`

Uma exceção  `StackOverflowException` é lançada quando a pilha de execução excede por ter muitas chamadas de método aninhadas.

**Dicas associadas**:
Verifique se que você não tem um loop infinito ou recursão infinita.
Muitas chamadas de método são geralmente indicativos de recursão profunda ou irrestrita.

Fonte: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/w6sxk224.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Se o OP está falando que a Exception é lançada quando há o Connection.Open(), o que está gerando essa exceção provavelmente não está no caso da sua resposta...