# Speech recognition está dando stack overflow

Tags: c#, .net, método, reconhecimento-de-voz

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Speech.Synthesis; //namespace
using System.IO;
namespace SIF
{
    public class Falador
    {
        private static SpeechSynthesizer sp = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        public static void Falar(string text)
        {
            // caso ele esteja falando
            if (sp.State == SynthesizerState.Speaking)
                sp.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
            sp.SpeakAsync(text);
        }

        public static void Speak(params string [] texts)
        {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                Speak(texts[rnd.Next(1, texts.Length)]);
        }
    }
}
```

Esse código e para o meu assistente escolher entre diversas palavras em C# por exemplo:

```
Falador.Speak("Tudo bem", "Como desejar");
```

então ele escolheria uma dessas palavras e falaria porem acontece o seguinte erro:

> System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'

Como posso resolver?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Você está chamando o método `Speak()` dentro do método `Speak()`. Isto chama-se [recursão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101), até aí sem problemas ainda que na maioria dos casos não seja necessário. Só que em algum momento isto precisa parar, caso contrário entrará em chamadas infinitas e [estourará a pilha de execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101).

Não posso afirmar qual a solução porque a pergunta não diz muito, mas pode ser que só queria fazer um laço (embora acho que também seria um erro, mas não posso falar sem conhecer essa API).

O mais provável que tenha sido feito por acidente, aí teria ver o que realmente quer, se quer chamar esse método recursivamente, pode ser que queria ter outro método aí. Pode até ser que está usando o mesmo nome do método da API, então precisaria trocar o nome do seu ou então chamar o nome do método da API de forma completamente qualificado, ou seja, através do [*namespace*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101).

Leia:

- [O que é uma recursão de cauda?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184494/101)
- [O que é um método recursivo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/323954/101)
- [Qual é a vantagem de usarmos funções recursivas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101)