# Como é que o programa dá o produto dos 2 números que eu coloco na consola?

Tags: c

Este programa faz o produto de 2 números ou seja se eu coloco 3 e 4 o resultado é 12 se coloco 4 e 4 é 16. Mas eu nâo percebo como faz o produto através do `sum(x+1,y-1)` e do  `sum(x, product(x, y-1)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum(int x, int y)
{
    return y == 0 ? x : sum(x+1, y-1);
}

int product(int x, int y)
{
    return y == 0 ? 0 : sum(x, product(x, y-1));
}

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
    int z = product(x, y);
    printf("%d\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você já estudou recursividade?

Comment: Aconselho a fazer passo a passo para entender, tipo `product(3,4) => sum(3, product(3,4-1)) => etc`

Comment: Faça o teste de mesa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/101 e leia sobre https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/323954/101.