# Como que esse código de transformar o número em binário funciona?

Tags: java, algoritmo, recursão

Estou tentando entender essa função que chama ela mesma, porém não entra na cabeça como que ela consegue transformar um numero em binário sem ao menos uma repetição, como funciona?

```
static int numeroBinario(int n) {
    if(n > 0) {
        numeroBinario(n/2);// essa parte repete a chamada até o numero ser 0? é isso?
        System.out.print(n % 2);
        return n;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 7):

Isso é chamado recursão. Acho que o grosso da explicação está em [O que é um método recursivo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/323954/101).

Há uma repetição sim, só não há um comando de controle que diga para repetir, a repetição se dá justamente por a função chamar a si própria. Se chama algo várias vezes está **repetindo** a chamada.

Como uma estrutura como um `while` ou `for` sabe que deve encerrar a repetição? Tem uma condição que decide isso. Na sua função também tem uma condição que decide quando parar a **repetição** de chamar a função novamente.

O comentário no código está certo, mas dá margem para uma interpretação errada, assim fica melhor:

```
static int numeroBinario(int n) {
    if (n > 0) { //o número ainda é maior que zero?
        numeroBinario(n / 2); //repete a chamada
        System.out.print(n % 2); //executa uma ação
    }
    return n;
}
```

Parece bobo mas naquela linha não tinha condição alguma, mas o comentário dava a entender que ali tinha uma decisão a ser tomada. Pode ser que tinha entendido certo, mas não estava escrito certo. Programar é fazer certo o tempo todo. Programação não tem margem para fazer mais ou menos, isso é coisa de humanos.

Percebeu que eu dei uma simplificada?

O mesmo código escrito de forma interativa:

```
int n = 120;
while (n > 0) { //o número ainda é maior que zero?
    System.out.print(n % 2); //executa uma ação
    n /= 2; //muda o próprio número
}
```

Na verdade esse código todo está errado. OU ele deveria ter um `void` como retorno ou ele deveria aproveitar o valor retornado para continuar fazendo o cálculo.

Até o nome do método não é bom, porque um método deveria indicar o que faz e não o que é. Assim fica melhor:

```
static void imprimeRepresetacaoBinariaParcial(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        ImprimeRepresetacaoBinariaParcial(n / 2);
        System.out.print(n % 2);
    }
    return n;
}
```

Parece muito longo? É, mas é isso que ele é. Ok, eu exagerei um pouco porque queria deixar claro que isso é uma representação e não um número binário.

Quase todo mundo aprende errado. Culpa de quem ensina errado porque aprendeu errado, por isso tem que tomar cuidado com o que usa para aprender. Quem aprendeu errado só pode ensinar errado.

Parte do nome longo é porque esse algoritmo fica melhor executado de forma interativa e não recursiva. Cada execução só imprime uma parte do resultado total então o nome está errado. E não tem como fazer certo de forma recursiva.

Algo assim seria o código mais próximo do ideal:

```
static void imprimeFormatoBinario(int n) {
    while (n > 0) {
        System.out.print(n % 2);
        n /= 2;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Recursion.java).

Veja mais em [Quando usar recursão e quando usar laços?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101) e [Qual é a vantagem de usarmos funções recursivas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101).

Comment: Valeu mesmo pela explicação!

Comment: @ArthurMaskalenkas veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.