# Melhor algoritmo para calcular fatorial

Tags: java, algoritmo, fatorial

Então, estou aprendendo a desenvolver em Java. O professor pediu para que eu desenvolvesse um método para o Fatorial. E que também mostrasse na Tela o que está acontecendo, por exemplo:

**3! = 3 X 2 X 1 = 6**

De fato, eu fiz isso acontecer, **porém existe alguma forma de o código ficar melhor?**:

```
    int n = Integer.parseInt(txtN.getValue().toString());        
    int f = 1; 
    int c = n; 
    String s = ""; 

    while(c>=1){ 
        f *= c;
        if (c == 1) {
            s += c; 
        } else if (c>1) {
            s += c + " x " ;
        }
        c--;
    }

    lblFat.setText(s + " = " + Integer.toString(f));
```

O código gera o fatorial e também deve mostrar na tela os números.

Exemplo

```
3! = 3 X 2 X 1 = 6
3! -> txtN (Local para o usuário inserir o número)
6 -> lblFat (local que gera o resultado)
```

Fatorial em Java, tem um modo melhor de escrever o código?

Comment: Você pode usar a aproximação de Lanczos :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O mais comum é separar o cálculo da apresentação, mas em algo simples assim dá para entender. De acordo com o que foi colocado na pergunta eu faria assim (na verdade provavelmente eu usaria um `for`):

```
int f = 1; 
int c = n; 
String s = ""; 
while (c > 1) { 
    f *= c;
    s += c + " x " ;
    c--;
}
s += c;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6rZDLj). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xthueqzg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Factorial.java).

Para fazer de forma recursiva ficaria bem mais complicado, [ainda que não seja necessário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101).

Obviamente usando um inteiro simples há um limite restrito do máximo que poderá calcular o fatorial. Acredito que para esse exercício isso não seja problema, a intenção não é algo de produção e sim entender o funcionamento do algoritmo, mas vale saber que em certos casos um `BigInteger` cairia melhor, como foi comentado pelo Bruno Bermann.

Comment: Legal, já diminuiu algumas linhas de código e ficou mais claro.

Comment: Apenas complementando a resposta: O fatorial feito desta forma com integers limita-se ao tamanho limite da variável (int = 2^31-1 = 2147483647). É possível fazer com long ou com BigIntegers também. Este último limitaria virtualmente o tamanho do retorno do fatorial apenas pela memória disponível no sistema. Para verificar o retorno quando o valor é excedido faça um teste com o fatorial de 100, por exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Apresentando Fatoriais com for:

```
long fat=1;
String mult="";
for (int i=5; i>1; i--){
    fat *=i;
    mult +=i+" x ";
}
System.out.print(mult+"1 = "+fat);
```

Veja rodando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/MA3clU)

É mais recomendável que a variável que acumula os valores seja do tipo long, considerando que o int possui maior limitação de espectro.
Para alterar o valor, basta mudar o 5 por uma variável e escolher a forma de alimentá-la.

Ao final, foi adicionado o 1 fora da estrutura de repetição. Por ser fatorial, a multiplicação não é afetada pelo mesmo, podendo retirá-lo, economizando uma volta nos cálculos, apenas sendo agregado na string que já havia recebido o " X " após o 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class calculeFatorial{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int fatorial = 1;

    for (int i = 1;i < 11 ; i ++ ) {
      fatorial *= i;

      System.out.println("Fatorial de " +i+"=" +fatorial);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Não calcula o fatorial de 0

Answer (score 1):

Cara você  pode fazer recursivo.

```
Int FatorialRecursivo(int num){

   If(num==1) || (num==0)
      return 1;
   else
      return FatorialRecursivo(n-1)*n;
 }
```

Desculpa o código meio bagunçado eu to respondendo pelo APP,qualquer coisa pergunta se não entendeu a recursão.

Comment: Seu código funciona, mas não é adequado para grandes fatoriais, considerando o overhead que a recursão gera e o problema iminente de stack overflow.

Comment: @BrunoBermann Na verdade funciona para outra coisa diferente do que foi pedido na pergunta. Este é um fatorial genérico. Eu não quis negativar, mas não responde ao que foi perguntado.

Comment: @bigown Tem razão, o código não contempla o que foi pedido na pergunta, considerando o todo. Ainda assim exemplifica uma maneira diferente de fazer o cálculo do fatorial. Comentei em ambas as respostas (a sua e a do Nathan) para destacar os problemas que podem ocorrer em ambos algoritmos, caso alguém que venha a ler futuramente decida usar alguma delas em algum software mais "exigente", digamos assim.

Comment: O algoritmo pode até funcionar, o código não. Não existe `Int` e `If` em Java. E a condição `(num==1) || (num==0)` nunca funcionaria se não estivesse agrupada por um `(...)`.

Comment: @renan o código e o algoritmo, de acordo com a pergunta, estão errados, mesmo assim recebeu 3 votos, É o que gente sempre fala do voto dado automaticamente sem análise do conteúdo..

Answer (score 1):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercicio05For {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int resultadoFatorial = 1;
        StringBuilder multiplicador = new StringBuilder();

        System.out.println("Insira um número para descobrir seu respectivo Fatorial:");
        int fatorialDoNumero = sc.nextInt();

        while (fatorialDoNumero < 0) {
            System.out.println("Não é possível calcular o fatorial de números negativos!");
            System.out.println("Insira um número maior ou igual a zero para descobrir seu respectivo Fatorial:");
            fatorialDoNumero = sc.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = fatorialDoNumero; i > 1; i--) {
            resultadoFatorial *= i;
            multiplicador.append(i).append(" x ");
        }

        if (fatorialDoNumero == 0) {
            System.out.println(fatorialDoNumero + "! = " + resultadoFatorial);
        } else if (fatorialDoNumero == 1){
            System.out.println(fatorialDoNumero + "! = " + resultadoFatorial);
        } else {
            System.out.println(fatorialDoNumero + "! = " + multiplicador + "1 = " + resultadoFatorial);
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Caso queira deixar um número fatorial (sem entrada via teclado) basta remover o

`import java.util.Scanner;`, o `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);` e trocar o `sc.nextInt()` da variável `fatorialDoNumero` por um número inteiro ou por zero (nesse último caso, o resultado será 1)

Comment: Talvez o interesse ler [esse documento](https://sites.google.com/site/examath/research/factorials) é um método bastante rápido que foge do trivial. Uma boa implementação junto de uma boa explicação do funcionamento do algoritmo podem render alguns votos positivos.

Comment: @Marcos Alexandre pela sugestão de melhoria. Infelizmente só fiz depois de quebrar um pouco a cabeça, mas pelo menos me mostrou que estava no caminho certo.

Comment: @AugustoVasques obrigado pelo apontamento. O código agora está funcional. Vou estudar mais para refatorar futuramente o código. Se puder tirar a negativação, agradeço.

Comment: Funcionou: https://ideone.com/0tSE1j

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```
package test;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class FunctionalFactorial {

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface FactorialFunc<T> {
        T factorial (T t);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFactorial() {
        int value = 5;
        FactorialFunc<Integer>  f = (x) -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, value).reduce((i,j) -> i * j).getAsInt();
        Assert.assertEquals(120, f.factorial(value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

```
public int metodo(int valor){

        if(valor==1)
           return 1;

        else

         return (valor * metodo(valor -1)); //desmontando o numero 
               
    }
// UTLIZANDO RECURSIVIDADE
```

Comment: Explique melhor sua resposta.