# Como calcular o fatorial de um numero?

Tags: php

Já tentei, tentei e nada. Um programa que multiplique um número digitado por alguém em ordem decrescente.

Por exemplo:

digitei `7` e dei OK: `7x6x5x4x3x2x1`

deve aparecer o resultado disso tudo.

Código que já tenho:

```
<?php

    $n = $_GET['num'];
    $n2 = $n1;
    $tot = 0;

    while($n >= 1){
        $n2 = $n2 - 1;
        $tot = $n2 * $n2;
        $n--;
        echo "$tot <br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: @JeffersonJunior o que vc quer fazer exatamente?

Comment: Não coloque o print do código senão dificulta muito para quem for responder, use a opção `{ }` para formatar seu código. Aproveite e veja [como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ele quer calcular o fatorial de um número inteiro... só isso.

Comment: Relacionada: [Melhor algoritmo para calcular fatorial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150555/91) e [Fazer PHP imprimir o resultado da classe Fatorial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/206401/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então você quer calcular o fatorial de um número:

```
    $i = $_GET['num'];
    $calc = 1;
    while ($i > 1){
        $calc *= $i;
        $i--;
    }

    echo $calc;
```

Na matemática, o fatorial de um número natural n, representado por n!, é o produto de todos os inteiros positivos menores ou iguais a n.

Answer (score 2):

Se deseja calcular o fatorial de um numero, você pode utilizar a função [array_product](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-product.php) para calcular o produto dos valores contido no array que neste caso seria a sequencia gerada pela função `range()`.

Veja:

```
$numero = 7; //Pode vir de um GET ou POST

$v = array_product(range($numero, 1));
print_r($v);
```

Saída:

> 5040

Mais informações [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206432/27190).