# Recursão em C - O programa crasha

Tags: c, recursão

O objetivo do programa é pedir ao usuário dois algarismos e gerar uma lista de sequências, cada uma contendo informação da anterior.

Por exemplo:

O usuário escreve `1 1` e a lista gerada é:

- 21, porque a sequência anterior tem dois 1.
- 1211, porque a sequência anterior tem "um" 2 e "um" 1.
- 3112, porque a sequência anterior tem "três" 1 e "um" dois
- etc.

Quando tento correr o programa, crasha na 50ª linha e eu não faço ideia do porquê.

Agradeço a ajuda e peço desculpa a eventual irrelevância da questão.

Source:

```
#define Max_num   5000

typedef struct {
    int numero;
    int count;
}Numero;

typedef Numero Sequencia[Max_num];

// retorna comprimento da sequencia
int add_num ( Sequencia numeros , int n , int num){

    if ( n == 0) {
        numeros[0].numero = num;
        numeros[0].count = 1; 
        return n+1;

    }
    int i;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){

        if ( numeros[i].numero == num){
            numeros[i].count++;
            return n;
        }
    }

    numeros[n].numero = num;
    numeros[n].count = 1;
    return n+1;

}
void print_vetor(int vetor[] , int n){
    int i;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d",vetor[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}
void ler_sequencia(Sequencia numeros , int vetor[], int n){

    int i; //controla vetor recetor

    int x = 0;//controla sequencia
    for ( i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
        vetor[i] = numeros[x].count;
        i++;
        vetor[i] = numeros[x].numero;
        x++;

    }

}
void processar_vetor( int vetor[] , int n ){

        int i;
        Sequencia numeros;
        int c = 0;// comprimento da sequencia
        for ( i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
            c = add_num( numeros , c , vetor[i]);
        }
        int vetor_final[2*c];
        ler_sequencia( numeros , vetor_final , 2*c);
        print_vetor(vetor_final , 2*c);

        processar_vetor( vetor_final, 2*c);
    }


int main(){

    int vetor[2];
    printf("Escreve dois algarismos: ");
    scanf( "%d %d",&vetor[0] ,&vetor[1]);
    processar_vetor( vetor , 2 , 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu vou falar algo que eu tenho quase certeza será ignorado por alguma razão. O problema desse algoritmo é que ele não é adequado para usar recursão. Aí fica complicado fazer certo. Eu sei que pode ser que alguém mandou, que pode ser que está fazendo para aprender, mas o ideal é aprender fazer algo que seja inerentemente recursivo e não forçar a barra em algo que não é. Veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101

Comment: Compreendo , mas eu gostava de perceber qual é o problema concreto com o código que escrevi, porque é que só funciona até à 50º recursão?

Comment: (1) acho que esse programa nem compila, a declaração de "processar_vetor" está diferente do uso (2) a função "processar_vetor" precisar ter um critério de parada, senão fica em loop infinito e vai dar crash mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Como @José X comentou, todo programa em recursão deve ter um critério de parada. No seu caso o problema é que você está alocando estaticamente infinitos vetores de inteiros chamados "numeros" de acordo com sua variável, uma hora você terá alocado tanta memória que irá "invadir" o espaço de outro programa e o SO irá parar o mesmo.

Para consertar você deve ou criar uma parada, no seu caso de modo grotesco, mas fácil, poderia fazer a função processar_vetor retornar um inteiro e limitar o número de iterações verificando a cada chamada do mesmo se esse número alcançou o limite, ou se realmente quiser que o programa rode indefinidamente até um sinal de kill seja enviado pelo usuário você deve alocar dinamicamente a memória do novo vetor a cada iteração da função processar_vetor e ao final você deve dar free no vetor que não será mais utilizado.