# Recursividade números pares em C++

Tags: c++, recursão

O objetivo do código abaixo é, através de um método recursivo, retornar a quantidade de numeros pares entre dois números colocados pelo usuário. Não consigo entender por que o meu método `quant` só retorna 0.

```
#include <iostream>

int quant(int num1, int num2){
    int resul = 0;
    if((num1<num2) && (num1%2==0)){
        resul += quant((num1+1),num2);
        return resul;
    } else {
        return resul;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int n1,n2;

    printf("Digite o primeiro numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    printf("Digite o segundo numero, maior que o primeiro: ");
    scanf("%d", &n2);

    int pares;
    pares = quant(n1,n2);
    printf("A quantidade de pares entre  %d %s %d %s %d",n1," e ",n2," e: ",pares);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Olhe seu caso básico. O `else`. Ele só pode retornar 0. O caso recursivo retorna 0 + valor da chamada recursiva. O que resulta em apenas 0.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

Como eu disse em comentário, seu valor básico é 0. O resultado recursivo é 0 + retorno do próximo passo recursivo. Então você **não consegue sair do 0**. Pode fazer quantos passos recursivos quiser, sempre retornará 0, pois em nenhum momento há acréscimo de valores.

A correção envolve duas coisas:

1. o caso base é apenas é *unicamente apenas* quando o primeiro argumento for menor do que o segundo, retornando 0
2. quando encontrar um par no primeiro argumento, marque como par e retorne 1 + resultado da chamada recursiva; caso não for par, retorne só o resultado da chamada recursiva

Essa condição de parada evita imediatamente que se entre em recursão infinita.

Simplesmente com essas condições, o código seria escrito assim:

```
int contaParesRecursivo(int num1, int num2) {
  if (num1 > num2) {
    return 0;
  }
  int ehPar = num1 % 2 == 0? 1: 0;
  return ehPar + contaParesRecursivo(num1 + 1, num2);
}
```

---

De toda sorte, como esse problema é claramente não recursivo, eu preferiria resolvê-lo em [`o(1)`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56836/64969). No caso, a resposta de apenas um passo seria assim:

```
int contaParesO1(int num1, int num2) {
  if (num1 > num2) {
    return 0;
  }
  return (num2/2) - ((num1 -1)/2);
}
```

Explicando:

- `x/2` em operação inteira retorna *exatamente* quantos números pares há no intervalo `(0, x]`
- `num1-1` nesse caso serve para pegar tornar o intervalo aberto no limite superior; a fórmula então para a quantidade de pares se aplicará então ao intervalo `(0, num1 - 1]`, que no caso é idêntico a `(0, num1)` nos inteiros
- assim, a quantidade de pares no intervalo `[num1, num2]` é transformado na quantidade de pares no intervalo `(0, num2]` menos a quantidade de pares no intervalo `(0, num1)`
- a condição inicial que retorna 0 garante que não seja passado um intervalo invertido

  > sem essa condição o resultado de `contaParesO1(10,1)` seria -4, o que não faria muito sentido
- essa fórmula só funciona para números naturais diferentes de 0

Answer (score 1):

Eu [costumo dizer que recursão é abusada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101). Fazem onde é mais simples fazer um laço. Mas se é para fazer recursão tem que ser no estilo funcional. Funções recursivas com mais de uma linha costumam estar filosoficamente erradas, mesmo que o resultado esteja certo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int quant(int num1, int num2) {
    return num1 < num2 ? quant(num1 + 1, num2) + (num1 % 2 == 0) : 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n1,n2;
    printf("Digite o primeiro numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    printf("Digite o segundo numero, maior que o primeiro: ");
    scanf("%d", &n2);
    printf("A quantidade de pares entre %d e %d e' %d", n1, n2, quant(n1, n2));
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QvdjOS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vghjrtyl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/Recursion.c).

Agora a função está com cara de recursiva. Foi difícil enxergar assim porque este não é um problema tão claramente adequado para recursão.

Toda função recursiva tem que ter um *branch*, ou seja, uma decisão que indique quando deve terminar a recursão, assim como todo laço tem uma condição de saída. Se não fizer isto ou entra em *loop* infinito ou dá um valor padrão se fizer algo que impeça a recursão infinita.

O que eu fiz é estabelecer qual é a condição que termina a recursão e ela é uma só:

```
num1 < num2
```

Esta é a condição que terminaria o laço e é isso que eu usei para decidir o fim, e só no fim é que o valor deve ser 0. No seu código ele vale 0 em todos os casos, por isso dá 0.

Mas tem uma condição que determina se deve somar 1 ou não. Isso em código mais imperativo seria um `if` e não poderia estar junto da condição de saída da recursão. Juntar ambas foi um outro erro. Isso seria a verificação se é par ou não:

```
num1 % 2 == 0
```

Na verdade em C é comum fazer apenas:

```
num1 & 1
```

Não usei `if` porque é um pouco caro e neste caso não é necessário, afinal o resultado desta conta será 0 ou 1, que é o mesmo resultado que um `if` gera, então melhor não usá-lo já que o custo será menor (se o compilador não conseguir otimizar).

Use o operador condicional para ficar em uma linha. Em código estilo funcional o estilo imperativo com `if` fica esquisito.