# Algoritmo recursivo para calcular média aritmética

Tags: python, recursão

Estou fazendo um algoritmo que tem que calcular a média dos valores de uma lista, mas com o que eu fiz não apresenta o resultado correto. A soma dá certo, mas na hora de dividir não.

```
def media(l,s=0):
    if len(l) == 0:
        return s
    else:
        return media(l[1:],s+l[0]) / len(l)

media()
```

Comment: Gabriel, seja bem vindo, pode colocar mais parte do seu código? O que faz o `b([3,4,5,4])` ?

Comment: Essa parte era um teste, esqueci de retirar!! Muito obrigada pela recepçao. Então o código é só isso, acho que por isso ta dando erro,mas não sei oq fazer mais

Comment: Que resposta você está obtendo @GabrielBorges? Algum erro está sendo apresentado?

Comment: @GabrielBorges tente fazer assim no else: `else:
            val = media(l[1:],s+l[0]) / len(l)
            return val`

Comment: Tipo, vamos supor que eu use l = [3,6,7], deveria retornar a media,que no caso é 8, porém tanto do modo como eu apresentei quanto ao do @LuizAugusto da como resultado 0,666...  Não sei como consertar

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Apenas lembrando que recursão não é a melhor maneira de calcular a média (e mais abaixo veremos os motivos). De qualquer forma, seguem algumas alternativas.*</sup>

---

No seu código, a cada chamada recursiva você cria uma sub-lista contendo do segundo elemento em diante (`l[1:]`), e você divide o resultado pelo tamanho destas sub-listas (ou seja, se a lista original tem 3 elementos, `l[1:]` terá 2 elementos e você somará estes 2 elementos e dividirá o resultado por 2, para depois somar com o primeiro elemento e dividir tudo por 3, por isso não funciona). O certo seria dividir só no final, quando você já tiver a soma total de todos os elementos.

Sendo assim, uma alternativa é controlar o índice do elemento em que estamos para saber se devo dividir ou não:

```
def media_recursiva(valores, i = 0, n = None):
    if n is None: # se n não foi passado, usar o tamanho da lista
        n = len(valores)

    # último elemento, retorna o próprio
    if i == n - 1:
        return valores[i] 

    # dividir por n toda a soma computada 
    if i == 0:
        return (valores[i] + media_recursiva(valores, i + 1, n)) / n

    # computar soma (sem dividir)
    return valores[i] + media_recursiva(valores, i + 1, n)

print(media_recursiva([3, 6, 7])) # 5.333333333333333
```

Repare que somente quando `i` for zero, eu faço a divisão por `n` (que no caso é o tamanho da lista, ou seja, a quantidade de números). Nos demais casos, eu só somo os valores. Outra vantagem com relação à sua função é que não precisa criar uma sub-lista, pois os valores de `i` já controlam o índice do elemento que quero pegar, então posso passar a mesma lista em todas as chamadas recursivas.

---

Outra alternativa (tão ou até mais ineficiente que a anterior) é ir somando e dividindo, e multiplicando de volta, a cada chamada recursiva.

```
def media_recursiva2(valores, n = None):
    if n is None:
        n = len(valores)

    if n == 1:
        return valores[0]

    return (valores[n - 1] + ((n - 1) * media_recursiva2(valores, n - 1))) / n

print(media_recursiva2([3, 6, 7])) # 5.333333333333333
```

Basicamente, sempre dividimos o valor por `n` (que por sua vez diminui seu valor a cada chamada recursiva), e multiplicamos de volta para obter o valor original.

A ideia básica é que para calcular a média de N valores, eu primeiro calculo a média de N - 1 valores (que será a soma desses N - 1 valores, dividida por N - 1). Em seguida, para que a soma corresponda ao N-ésimo valor mais a soma dos N - 1 restantes, eu multiplico esta média por N - 1 antes de somar com o N-ésimo valor, para que no final eu tenha a soma dos N valores. Depois é só dividir tudo por N.

É basicamente o algoritmo que você estava tentando fazer (dividir sempre a cada chamada recursiva), mas com uma multiplicação para "anular" os efeitos das divisões feitas anteriormente. Uma volta bem "feia" e ineficiente, por sinal.

---

Para finalizar, gostaria de deixar claro que usar um algoritmo recursivo para calcular média não é a melhor solução. Mesmo se for um exercício para estudar recursão, ainda sim é questionável, já que é um péssimo caso de uso para este recurso (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107662/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052)).

Além disso, dependendo do tamanho da lista, a quantidade de chamadas recursivas [pode causar um estouro de pilha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001). E a lista [nem precisa ser tão grande assim](https://ideone.com/HCKZUi).

Se quer calcular a média de uma maneira mais simples e direta, faça:

```
def media(valores):
    return sum(valores) / len(valores)
```

---

<sup>Os algoritmos recursivos acima foram retirados [daqui](http://www.iitk.ac.in/esc101/08Jan/lecnotes/lecture22.pdf) e [daqui](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-average-array-iterative-recursive/).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Você deseja a média de uma lista passada para uma função recursivamente, então faça isto:

```
l=[3,6,7]

def media(l):


    if len(l) == 1:

        return l[0]
    else:
        return  l[0] + media(l[1:])

media(l)
print("A média da sua lista é: ", (media(l)/len(l)))
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/2Xm1wS)

Observe que foi aprimorada sua condição de parada para quando a lista conter 1 elemento:   `len(l)==1`.

A média da lista `l[3,6,7]` é `5.33` e não `8` conforme você citou nos comentários.

Comment: Entendi!! Mas teria alguma forma de fazer a divisão dentro da função, pq quero retornar o resultado e não printar???

Comment: @GabrielBorges entendi o que você quer, ainda hoje modifico a resposta!

Comment: Já consegui!! Mas muito obrigada por sua disponibilidade