# Função recursiva para calcular a média

Tags: c, recursão

Fiz essa função `media()` que calcula a média dos elementos presentes em um vetor de 5 elementos. Porém, a função está retornando `2` ao invés da média correta.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int media(int vet[], int tam);

int main() {
  int vet[5] = {4, 2, 1, 6, 7};

  printf("%d", media(vet, 5));

  return 0;
}

int media(int vet[], int tam) {
  if (tam == 0)
    return 0;
  else
    return vet[tam - 1]/5 + media(vet, tam - 1);
}
```

Comment: Só um detalhe pessoal, quando eu escrevi "A função está retornando..." eu quis dizer: "A função está retornado 2 ao invés da média".

Comment: Note que você está trabalhando com inteiros. Dos seus 5 valores apenas 2 são maiores que 5, mas são menores que 10, e portanto a divisão resultará em 1, nos demais (menores que 5) a divisão retornará 0. Daí seu resultado ser 2.

Comment: Relacionado: [Algoritmo recursivo para calcular média aritmética](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/424918/112052)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursão não é adequado para fazer esse tipo de algoritmo. Em geral isso é pedido como exercício para aprender o mecanismo, mas aí a pessoa aprende a decidir pelo uso de forma errada. É muito mais simples fazer de forma iterativa. Se a soma fosse feita de forma recursiva e depois divido para achar a média até seria aceitável.

Mas como o exercício desensina e pede recursão vou responder o que ele pede. Tem um erro aí porque a divisão só pode ocorrer no final do processo, ou seja, quando estiver na primeira chamada da função, que é onde a recursão será encerrada, então precisa mais uma condição para testar se está nessa execução.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int media(int vet[], int posicao) {
    if (posicao == 0) return 0;
    else if (posicao == 5) return (vet[posicao - 1] + media(vet, posicao - 1)) / 5;
    else return vet[posicao - 1] + media(vet, posicao - 1);
}

int main() {
    int vet[5] = {4, 2, 1, 6, 7};
    printf("%d", media(vet, 5));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/M0jnhn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/AverageRecursivec). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/AverageRecursive.c).

Eu troquei o nome da variável também porque ela não é o tamanho e sim a posição que está lidando naquele momento. Não muda a execução, mas torna o código muito mais legível.

Apenas para comparar a forma iterativa como é mais simples e mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) (o recursivo pode ser mais DRY, mas fica mais complicado ainda):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int media(int vet[]) {
    int soma = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) soma += vet[i]; 
    return soma / 5; 
}

int main() {
    int vet[5] = {4, 2, 1, 6, 7};
    printf("%d", media(vet));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9qCXZS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/AverageIterativec). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/AverageIterative.c).