# Jogar novamente, tabuleiro não "limpa" - Jogo da Velha Python

Tags: python

Estou com um problema nesse código, é um jogo da velha para faculdade, ele está funcionando normal, mas na parte que coloquei pra jogar novamente, quando usuário digitar sim, ele não zera o tabuleiro, e fica com as marcações da partida anterior. Como faço para ele limpar as marcações, zerar o tabuleiro?

```py
print('Bem Vindo ao Jogo da Velha! Vamos começar!')

print('-=-'*15)


def tabuleiro(**posicao):


    print('  {}  |  {}  |  {}  '.format(posicao['pos1'], posicao['pos2'], posicao['pos3']))
    print('------+------+------')
    print('  {}  |  {}  |  {}  '.format(posicao['pos4'], posicao['pos5'], posicao['pos6']))
    print('------+------+------')
    print('  {}  |  {}  |  {}  '.format(posicao['pos7'], posicao['pos8'], posicao['pos9']))


contar_jogadas = 0
def pedir_jogada(lista_totalpalpites):

    print('-=-'*15)
    while True:
        jogada = input('Digite uma posição no tabuleiro para jogar: ')

        if jogada.isdigit():
            jogada = int(jogada)
            if jogada in lista_totalpalpites:
                break
            else: 
                print('Você digitou um número já pedido, tente novamente')
        else:
                print('Você não digitou um número válido, tente novamente')
    print('-=-'*15)        
    return jogada




def verifica_jogada(jogada, numero_jogadas, **posicao): 

    for key, value in posicao.items():
        if jogada == value:
            if numero_jogadas % 2 == 0:
                    posicao[key] = 'X'
            else:
                    posicao[key] = 'O'
    return posicao



def procurar_vencedor(**posicao):

    possiveis_1 = posicao['pos1'] == posicao['pos4'] == posicao['pos7']
    possiveis_2 = posicao['pos1'] == posicao['pos2'] == posicao['pos3']
    possiveis_3 = posicao['pos1'] == posicao['pos5'] == posicao['pos9']
    possiveis_4 = posicao['pos2'] == posicao['pos5'] == posicao['pos8']
    possiveis_5 = posicao['pos3'] == posicao['pos6'] == posicao['pos9']
    possiveis_6 = posicao['pos4'] == posicao['pos5'] == posicao['pos6']
    possiveis_7 = posicao['pos7'] == posicao['pos8'] == posicao['pos9']
    possiveis_8 = posicao['pos3'] == posicao['pos5'] == posicao['pos7']


lista_possiveis = [possiveis_1, possiveis_2, possiveis_3, possiveis_4, possiveis_5, possiveis_6, possiveis_7, possiveis_8]


    for possiveis in lista_possiveis:
        if possiveis == True:
            print('Temos um vencedor! Parabéns!')
            return True
        elif contar_jogadas == 8:
            print('Deu velha! Ninguém ganhou.')
            return True



posicao = 
{
    'pos1': 1,
    'pos2': 2,
    'pos3': 3,
    'pos4': 4,
    'pos5': 5,
    'pos6': 6,
    'pos7': 7,
    'pos8': 8,
    'pos9': 9
}


lista_totalpalpites = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]



def denovo():
    jogar_denovo = input('''
Deseja jogar novamente?
Digite S para SIM ou N para NÃO.
''')

    if jogar_denovo.upper() == 'S':
        print('Bem Vindo ao Jogo da Velha! Vamos começar!')
        print('-=-'*15)
    elif jogar_denovo.upper() == 'N':
        print('Até logo!')
    else:
        denovo()


while True:

    tabuleiro(**posicao)
    jogada = pedir_jogada(lista_totalpalpites)
    lista_totalpalpites[jogada - 1] = 'X'
    posicao = verifica_jogada(jogada, contar_jogadas, **posicao)
    if procurar_vencedor(**posicao): 
        tabuleiro(**posicao)
        denovo()

    contar_jogadas += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Dá para simplificar bastante o código e melhorar/corrigir vários detalhes:

## Escolha a estrutura de dados adequada

Para o tabuleiro, você criou um dicionário com as chaves "pos1", "pos2", etc. Sempre que você tiver um dicionário cujas chaves são "alguma coisa 1", "alguma coisa 2", etc, é sinal de que **provavelmente** você deveria usar uma lista, e não um dicionário. Listas possuem posições numéricas sequenciais por definição, e usar dicionários neste caso não traz vantagem alguma e só complica o código à toa.

Pode até parecer um detalhe besta, mas [escolher a estrutura de dados adequada é meio caminho andado para um programa melhor](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/163185). Saiba [quais são as estruturas que a linguagem disponibiliza](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) (e principalmente, como elas funcionam) e use a mais adequada para cada caso.

A única "complicação" é que os índices de uma string começam com zero, mas acostume-se a isso, pois é assim que as linguagens funcionam ("praticamente tudo" na programação começa do índice zero).

## Dê nomes melhores

Você chamou o tabuleiro de `posicao`, mas a variável deveria se chamar `tabuleiro` (ou então `posicoes`, no plural), pois ela não é **uma** posição, e sim o conjunto de todas as posições (ou seja, ela **é** o tabuleiro).

Também pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad). No código abaixo você verá que mudei outros nomes também.

## Validar se foi digitado um número

Não use [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit), pois há vários caracteres para os quais `isdigit()` retorna `True`, mas dão erro ao converter para número com [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int). Um exemplo é o `²` ([SUPERSCRIPT TWO](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm)), e há vários outros (veja a lista completa [aqui](https://ideone.com/noYWWm)).

> *"Ah, mas é só um exercício, o usuário sempre vai digitar números válidos."*

Se for assim, bastaria converter para `int` direto, sem precisar testar se é dígito (ou seja, `isdigit()` também não seria necessário neste caso). Se o usuário vai digitar algo, esteja preparado para receber "qualquer coisa" e só prossiga se tiver certeza que o dado é válido.

A maneira mais garantida é simplesmente converter para `int`, e capturar o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) para saber se deu erro.

Há outros detalhes para arrumar, como:

- não chame a função `denovo()` dentro dela mesma. Apesar de "funcionar", você está fazendo uma [chamada recursiva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/112052), e poderá haver um estouro de pilha se o usuário não digitar nem "S" nem "N" por muitas vezes seguidas ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/723QxP) um exemplo - role até o final da página e veja o erro de *stack overflow*). Use um *loop* simples e pronto.
- coloque todas as tarefas repetitivas em funções (até mesmo o `print('-=-'*15)`, que apesar de ser uma única linha, se repete várias vezes, então se você quiser mudá-la, terá que mudar em vários lugares; já usando uma função, você só muda em um lugar e pronto)
- não precisa passar os parâmetros com *unpack* (ou seja, com os asteriscos antes: `funcao(**valor)` não é necessário no seu caso - [veja aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786102/unpacking-function-argument) um exemplo de caso em que seria necessário)
- também é interessante verificar se a posição escolhida é válida, pois o usuário pode digitar `100`, e ao tentar acessar a posição 100 do tabuleiro, dará erro
- tem outros detalhezinhos que você poderá ver no código a seguir

```
def mostrar_separador():
    print('-=-' * 15)

def criar_tabuleiro(): # cria um tabuleiro vazio
    return list(range(1, 10)) # lista com os números entre 1 e 9

def mostrar_tabuleiro(tabuleiro):
    print('  {}  |  {}  |  {}  '.format(*tabuleiro[:3]))  # mostra as 3 primeiras posições
    print('------+------+------')
    print('  {}  |  {}  |  {}  '.format(*tabuleiro[3:6])) # mostra da quarta à sexta posição
    print('------+------+------')
    print('  {}  |  {}  |  {}  '.format(*tabuleiro[6:]))  # mostra as 3 últimas posições

def pedir_jogada(tabuleiro, jogador):
    mostrar_separador()
    while True:
        try: # não use isdigit(), capture o ValueError
            print(f'jogador atual: {jogador}') # incluí esta mensagem para facilitar um pouco
            jogada = int(input('Digite uma posição no tabuleiro para jogar: '))
            if jogada <= 0 or jogada > len(tabuleiro): # verifica se o valor não está fora dos limites do tabuleiro
                print(f'Posição inválida: {jogada}')
            elif jogada in tabuleiro:
                mostrar_separador()
                return jogada # retorna direto, não precisa do break
            else: 
                print('Você digitou um número já pedido, tente novamente')
        except ValueError:
            print('Você não digitou um número válido, tente novamente')

def jogo_terminou(tabuleiro):
    posicoes_vencedoras = [
        [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], # horizontal
        [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], # vertical
        [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6] # diagonal
    ]
    # verifica todas as combinações de posições vencedoras
    for pos1, pos2, pos3 in posicoes_vencedoras:
        if tabuleiro[pos1] == tabuleiro[pos2] == tabuleiro[pos3]:
            print(f'Temos um vencedor: {tabuleiro[pos1]}! Parabéns!') # mudei a mensagem para mostrar quem ganhou
            # se já encontrei um vencedor, posso retornar direto (não precisa continuar verificando as outras combinações)
            return True

    # não tem vencedor, verifica se todas as posições estão ocupadas (não preciso mais do contador de jogadas)
    if all(posicao in ('X', 'O') for posicao in tabuleiro):
        print('Deu velha! Ninguém ganhou.')
        return True

    # jogo ainda não terminou
    return False


import sys

def verificar_jogar_novamente(): # mudei o nome "denovo" para algo mais significativo
    while True: # use um loop em vez de chamar a função dentro dela mesma
        jogar_denovo = input('''
Deseja jogar novamente?
Digite S para SIM ou N para NÃO.
''').upper() # já transforma em maiúscula aqui

        if jogar_denovo == 'S':
            mostrar_separador()
            break # sai do while
        elif jogar_denovo == 'N':
            print('Até logo!')
            sys.exit() # sai do programa
        else: # incluí uma mensagem a mais para ajudar o usuário
            print('Você deve digitar "S" ou "N"')

def dados_iniciais(): # o jogo começa com o jogador X e tabuleiro vazio
    print('Bem Vindo ao Jogo da Velha! Vamos começar!')
    return ('X', criar_tabuleiro())

jogador, tabuleiro = dados_iniciais()
while True:
    mostrar_tabuleiro(tabuleiro)

    # como o tabuleiro agora é uma lista, posso simplesmente marcar a jogada mudando-o diretamente
    # e ele substitui a lista_totalpalpites, que se torna redundante
    jogada = pedir_jogada(tabuleiro, jogador)
    tabuleiro[jogada - 1] = jogador
    jogador = 'O' if jogador == 'X' else 'X' # troca o jogador de X para O ou vice-versa

    if jogo_terminou(tabuleiro): 
        mostrar_tabuleiro(tabuleiro)
        verificar_jogar_novamente()
        # reinicio o tabuleiro
        jogador, tabuleiro = dados_iniciais()
```

Eu usei [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) para sair do programa. O problema é que ele sai mesmo, ou seja, se tivesse algum outro código depois do `while True`, ele não seria executado.

Uma outra opção é mudar a função `verificar_jogar_novamente` para retornar `True` ou `False`, indicando se o jogo deve continuar ou não, e então eu verifico isso no código:

```
def jogar_novamente(): # mudei o nome para "jogar_novamente"
    while True: # use um loop em vez de chamar a função dentro dela mesma
        jogar_denovo = input('''
Deseja jogar novamente?
Digite S para SIM ou N para NÃO.
''').upper() # já transforma em maiúscula aqui

        if jogar_denovo == 'S':
            mostrar_separador()
            return True # o jogo deve continuar
        elif jogar_denovo == 'N':
            print('Até logo!')
            return False # o jogo não deve continuar
        else: # incluí uma mensagem a mais para ajudar o usuário
            print('Você deve digitar "S" ou "N"')

...
jogador, tabuleiro = dados_iniciais()
while True:
    mostrar_tabuleiro(tabuleiro)

    # como o tabuleiro agora é uma lista, posso simplesmente marcar a jogada mudando-o diretamente
    # e ele substitui a lista_totalpalpites, que se torna redundante
    jogada = pedir_jogada(tabuleiro, jogador)
    tabuleiro[jogada - 1] = jogador
    jogador = 'O' if jogador == 'X' else 'X' # troca o jogador de X para O ou vice-versa

    if jogo_terminou(tabuleiro): 
        mostrar_tabuleiro(tabuleiro)
        if not jogar_novamente(): # se não é para jogar novamente, sai do while
            break # sai do while True
        # é para jogar novamente, reinicio o tabuleiro
        jogador, tabuleiro = dados_iniciais()
```

Assim ele sai do `while True`, mas não encerra o programa (ou seja, se tivesse algum código depois do `while`, ele seria executado, o que não ocorreria com `sys.exit()`).

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção, é criar uma função que retorna o tabuleiro vazio.

---

Você tem o seguinte trecho que inicializa o tabuleiro vazio:

```
posicao = 
{
    'pos1': 1,
    'pos2': 2,
    'pos3': 3,
    'pos4': 4,
    'pos5': 5,
    'pos6': 6,
    'pos7': 7,
    'pos8': 8,
    'pos9': 9
}
```

E também o que cria os palpites:

```
lista_totalpalpites = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Criamos então uma função que retorna esse valor do tabuleiro vazio:

```
def tabuleiroVazio():
  return {
      'pos1': 1,
      'pos2': 2,
      'pos3': 3,
      'pos4': 4,
      'pos5': 5,
      'pos6': 6,
      'pos7': 7,
      'pos8': 8,
      'pos9': 9
  }
```

E também uma que retorna os palpites vazios:

```
def palpitesVazios():
  return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Passamos então a inicializar a variável `posicao` com o retorno da função `tabuleiroVazio`:

```
posicao = tabuleiroVazio()
```

E a `lista_totalpalpites` com a `palpitesVazios`:

```
lista_totalpalpites = palpitesVazios()
```

Agora no trecho que você verifica o final de jogo, você chama novamente a função `tabuleiroVazio` e a `palpitesVazios`:

```
if procurar_vencedor(**posicao): 
    posicao = tabuleiroVazio()
    lista_totalpalpites = palpitesVazios()
    tabuleiro(**posicao)
    denovo()
```

---

Além disso, perceba que mesmo optando por não jogar novamente, o jogo prossegue, isso porque seu `while True` não tem nenhum break, não tem uma forma de sair do loop.

Podemos alterar a função `denovo` para passar a retornar um boolean e com base nele fazer o `break` do `while`:

```
def denovo():
    jogar_denovo = input('''
Deseja jogar novamente?
Digite S para SIM ou N para NÃO.
''')

    if jogar_denovo.upper() == 'S':
        print('Bem Vindo ao Jogo da Velha! Vamos começar!')
        print('-=-'*15)
        return True
    elif jogar_denovo.upper() == 'N':
        print('Até logo!')
        return False
    else:
        return denovo()
```

Caso então ela retorna `False`, significa que não devemos seguir no loop e o jogo é encerrado:

```
if not denovo():
  break
```

---

Seu código ficará então mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
print('Bem Vindo ao Jogo da Velha! Vamos começar!')

print('-=-'*15)

def tabuleiro(**posicao):
    print('  {}  |  {}  |  {}  '.format(posicao['pos1'], posicao['pos2'], posicao['pos3']))
    print('------+------+------')
    print('  {}  |  {}  |  {}  '.format(posicao['pos4'], posicao['pos5'], posicao['pos6']))
    print('------+------+------')
    print('  {}  |  {}  |  {}  '.format(posicao['pos7'], posicao['pos8'], posicao['pos9']))

contar_jogadas = 0

def pedir_jogada(lista_totalpalpites):

    print('-=-'*15)
    while True:
        jogada = input('Digite uma posição no tabuleiro para jogar: ')

        if jogada.isdigit():
            jogada = int(jogada)
            if jogada in lista_totalpalpites:
                break
            else: 
                print('Você digitou um número já pedido, tente novamente')
        else:
                print('Você não digitou um número válido, tente novamente')
    print('-=-'*15)        
    return jogada

def verifica_jogada(jogada, numero_jogadas, **posicao): 

    for key, value in posicao.items():
        if jogada == value:
            if numero_jogadas % 2 == 0:
                    posicao[key] = 'X'
            else:
                    posicao[key] = 'O'
    return posicao

def procurar_vencedor(**posicao):

    possiveis_1 = posicao['pos1'] == posicao['pos4'] == posicao['pos7']
    possiveis_2 = posicao['pos1'] == posicao['pos2'] == posicao['pos3']
    possiveis_3 = posicao['pos1'] == posicao['pos5'] == posicao['pos9']
    possiveis_4 = posicao['pos2'] == posicao['pos5'] == posicao['pos8']
    possiveis_5 = posicao['pos3'] == posicao['pos6'] == posicao['pos9']
    possiveis_6 = posicao['pos4'] == posicao['pos5'] == posicao['pos6']
    possiveis_7 = posicao['pos7'] == posicao['pos8'] == posicao['pos9']
    possiveis_8 = posicao['pos3'] == posicao['pos5'] == posicao['pos7']

    lista_possiveis = [possiveis_1, possiveis_2, possiveis_3, possiveis_4, possiveis_5, possiveis_6, possiveis_7, possiveis_8]

    for possiveis in lista_possiveis:
        if possiveis == True:
            print('Temos um vencedor! Parabéns!')
            return True
        elif contar_jogadas == 8:
            print('Deu velha! Ninguém ganhou.')
            return True

def tabuleiroVazio():
  return {
      'pos1': 1,
      'pos2': 2,
      'pos3': 3,
      'pos4': 4,
      'pos5': 5,
      'pos6': 6,
      'pos7': 7,
      'pos8': 8,
      'pos9': 9
  }

def palpitesVazios():
  return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

posicao = tabuleiroVazio()

lista_totalpalpites = palpitesVazios()

def denovo():
    jogar_denovo = input('''
Deseja jogar novamente?
Digite S para SIM ou N para NÃO.
''')

    if jogar_denovo.upper() == 'S':
        print('Bem Vindo ao Jogo da Velha! Vamos começar!')
        print('-=-'*15)
        return True
    elif jogar_denovo.upper() == 'N':
        print('Até logo!')
        return False
    else:
        return denovo()

while True:

    tabuleiro(**posicao)
    jogada = pedir_jogada(lista_totalpalpites)
    lista_totalpalpites[jogada - 1] = 'X'
    posicao = verifica_jogada(jogada, contar_jogadas, **posicao)

    if procurar_vencedor(**posicao): 
        posicao = tabuleiroVazio()
        lista_totalpalpites = palpitesVazios()
        tabuleiro(**posicao)
        if not denovo():
          break

    contar_jogadas += 1
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/CluelessIcyAddon