# Multiplas condições em um if

Tags: python, if, jogos

Bom, eu estou trabalhando em um jogo da velha, o código completo desta função "win_check" é:

```
history = []
    def win_check():
        one = " "
        two = " "
        three = " "
        four = " "
        five = " "
        six = " "
        seven = " "
        eight = " "
        nine = " "
        for i in history:
            if "x" in i:
                if "1" in i:
                    one = "x"
                elif "2" in i:
                    two = "x"
                elif "3" in i:
                    three = "x"
                elif "4" in i:
                    four = "x"
                elif "5" in i:
                    five = "x"
                elif "6" in i:
                    six = "x"
                elif "7" in i:
                    seven = "x"
                elif "8" in i:
                    eight = "x"
                elif "9" in i:
                    nine = "x"

            elif "o" in i:
                if "1" in i:
                    one = "o"
                elif "2" in i:
                    two = "o"
                elif "3" in i:
                    three = "o"
                elif "4" in i:
                    four = "o"
                elif "5" in i:
                    five = "o"
                elif "6" in i:
                    six = "o"
                elif "7" in i:
                    seven = "o"
                elif "8" in i:
                    eight = "o"
                elif "9" in i:
                    nine = "o"

            if (one and four and seven) == "x":
                print("Vitória do X!")
                sys.exit()
                
            if (one and four and seven) == "o":
                print("Vitória do O!")
                sys.exit()
```

Como podem ver, já tentei usar multiplos "and" no código, mas não funcionou. Quando uma linha é feita, mesmo se tiver uma bola ou um xis no meio, ele printa como vitória do último jogador.

Há alguma outra forma de adicionar várias condições à um "if" sem usar o "and" que os senhores e senhoras conheçam? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Talvez ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/446286/112052

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei se isso irá ajudar porque eu ainda estou aprendendo python, mas o python 3.10.0 tem uma função útil para acabar com os múltiplos ifs, a função **match case** é como se fosse o if, elif e else porém mais elegante. Um exemplo de como usar:

```py
def Converter(número=1):
    ''' Uma função que converte um número de 1 a 7 em dias da semana.'''
    match número:
        case 1:
            return 'Domingo'
        case 2:
            return 'Segunda-feira'
        case 3:
            return 'Terça-feira'
        case 4:
            return 'Quarta-feira'
        case 5:
            return 'Quinta-feira'
        case 6:
            return 'Sexta-feira'
        case 7:
            return 'Sábado'
        case _:
            print('O valor {} é inválido!'.format(número))
```

Na primeira linha eu defini a função **Converter** e dentro dos parênteses tem uma variável chamada **número** que se não colocar nenhum valor ao utilizar a função, automaticamente será atribuído o valor **1** a está variável devido ao **=1** após sua declaração.

Eu escrevi uma Docstring na segunda linha para explicar o que está função faz, não muda nada porém fica melhora a leitura do código por outras pessoas.

A função **match** veio agora na terceira linha e em seguida a variável número, ou seja, o python vai encontrar a condição verdadeira entre as outras condições sobre a variável número que vamos escrever a seguir.

Agora é como se fosse o if e o elif porém com algumas diferenças, o if e o elif se transformam em '**case condição**' que pode ser traduzido assim: **caso** o valor seja **1**(...).

E por fim na penúltima linha temos o 'else' que agora é '**case _**'.

Essa é uma forma de acabar com os múltiplos ifs de um código, espero ter ajudado pelo menos um pouco porque eu não sou muito bom para explicar. :c

(E caso tu queira saber o que eu fiz no resto do código é simples, o return retorna um valor e lá na última linha o método '.format()' coloca um valor dentro de chaves {} de uma string.)