# Reiniciar aplicação - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bom dia pessoal, tudo bem? Estou aprendendo ainda a programar em python, sou iniciante. Estou fazendo uma simples calculadora para fazer calculo de peso e custo de matéria prima. Queria que ele reiniciasse caso uma resposta fosse fora dos padrões necessários (atualmente o programa só trava para qualquer resposta errada). Se alguem puder me dar alguma dica por favor. Segue demonstração de como está, obrigado desde já.

```
while True:
    print("Utilize apenas valores com ponto, e não virgula!" '\n')
    tipo = input ("1020, 1045, 4340, ou 8620? ")
    if (tipo == "1020" or tipo == "1045"): ###1020###
        material = input('Chapa (C) ou barra (B)? ')
        if (material == "C" or material == "c"): ###CALCULO CHAPA###
            altura = float(input('ALTURA: '))
            largura = float (input ('LARGURA: '))
            comprimento = float (input ('COMPRIMENTO: '))
            peso= round ((altura * largura * comprimento * 7.85 / 1000000),3)
            resultado=print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> PESO CHAPA 1020/1045: {peso} KG <<<<<<<<\n')
            preço = round ((peso * 7),3)
            print (f'>>>>>>>> PREÇO: R$ {preço} <<<<<<<<\n')
            print ('DEFINA AS DIMENSÕES FINAIS DA PEÇA') ###DIMENSOES FINAIS CHAPA 1020###
            altura1 = float (input ("ALTURA FINAL: "))
            largura1 = float (input ("LARGURA FINAL: "))
            comprimento1 = float (input ("COMPRIMENTO FINAL: "))
            peso1= largura1 * altura1 * comprimento1 * 7.85 / 1000000
            resultado1=print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> PESO FINAL DA PEÇA: {peso1} KG <<<<<<<<\n')
        elif (material == "B" or material == "b"): ###CALCULO BARRA###
            diametro = float(input('DIAMETRO: '))
            comprimento = float (input ('COMPRIMENTO: '))
            peso= (diametro * diametro * 3.1416 * 7.85 / 4000) * (comprimento/1000)
            resultado=print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> PESO BARRA 1020/1045: {peso} KG <<<<<<<< \n') ###PESO###
            preço = peso * 7
            print (f'>>>>>>>> PREÇO: R$ {preço} <<<<<<<<\n') ###PREÇO###
            print ('DEFINA AS DIMENSÕES FINAIS DA PEÇA') ###DIMENSOES FINAIS BARRA 1020###
            diametro1 = float (input ("DIAMETRO FINAL: "))
            comprimento1 = float (input ("COMPRIMENTO FINAL: "))
            peso1 = (diametro1 * diametro1 * 3.1416 * 7.85 / 4000) * (comprimento1/1000)
            resultado1=print (f'\n>>>>>>>> PESO FINAL DA PEÇA {peso1} KG <<<<<<<<\n')                       
        tempera = input ("POSSUI TEMPERA? (S/N) ") ###TEMPERA###
        if (tempera == "S" or tempera == "s"):
            custotratamento= 6.10 * peso1
            print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> TEMPERA: R$ {custotratamento} <<<<<<<<\n')
        elif (tempera == "N" or tempera == "n"):
            custotratamento = 0
        oxidacao = input ("POSSUI OXIDAÇÃO? (S/N) ") ###OXIDAÇÃO###
        if (oxidacao == "S" or oxidacao == "s"):
            custooxidacao= 2 * peso1
            print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> OXIDAÇÃO: R$ {custooxidacao} <<<<<<<<\n')
        elif (oxidacao == "n" or oxidacao == "N"):
            custooxidacao = 0
            print ('\n')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema ocorre quando não é um digitado um número válido, e a conversão para [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) lança um [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError), o que encerra a execução do programa.

As outras respostas estão sugerindo colocar todo o código dentro de um `try`/`except`, o que de fato funcionaria. Mas aí qualquer erro em qualquer ponto do programa faria o *loop* se repetir novamente desde o início. Ou seja, se o usuário já digitou quase todos os valores e só deu erro no último, o programa voltaria para o início e pediria todos os valores novamente.

Não seria melhor se ele só pedisse para digitar novamente a informação que deu erro, e mantivesse as demais? Neste caso, a abordagem seria um pouco diferente.

De forma geral, você pode fazer um *loop* para uma informação específica, e só pedir que digite novamente em caso de erro. Um algoritmo mais geral seria algo como:

```
repetir enquanto não tem dados válidos:
    ler o dado
    converter (para número, por exemplo)
    validar (se é um número mesmo, ou se o valor é um dos válidos ("s" ou "n", por exemplo))
    se deu erro, volta para início do loop
    se o valor é válido, sai do loop
```

Em Python, uma alternativa para isso seria:

```
def ler_valores(mensagem, mensagem_erro=None, conversao=None, valores_validos=None):
    while True:
        try:
            dado = input(mensagem)
            if conversao: # se tem conversão a ser feita
                dado = conversao(dado)
            if valores_validos: # se tem uma lista de valores válidos
                if dado in valores_validos: # verifica se é um dos valores válidos
                    return dado
                else:
                    print('Você só pode digitar um dos valores válidos:', ', '.join(map(str, valores_validos)))
            else:
                return dado
        except ValueError:
            print('digite um valor válido' if mensagem_erro is None else mensagem_erro)
```

Aí basta trocar o seu *loop* para usar esta função. Quando eu quero ler um número, a conversão é `float`, e quando estou lendo as opções (como "C"/"B", ou "S"/"N"), a conversão pode ser "transformar em maiúscula" e a lista de valores válidos são as respectivas letras. Ficaria assim:

```
tipos_validos = [ '1020', '1045', '4340', '8620' ]

while True:
    print("Utilize apenas valores com ponto, e não virgula!\n")
    tipo = ler_valores(f'Digite o tipo ({", ".join(map(str, tipos_validos))}): ', valores_validos=tipos_validos)
    if tipo == "1020" or tipo == "1045":
        material = ler_valores('Chapa (C) ou barra (B)? ', conversao=lambda s: s.upper(), valores_validos=['C', 'B'])
        if material == "C": ###CALCULO CHAPA###
            altura = ler_valores('ALTURA: ', conversao=float)
            largura = ler_valores('LARGURA: ', conversao=float)
            comprimento = ler_valores('COMPRIMENTO: ', conversao=float)
            peso = round(altura * largura * comprimento * 7.85 / 1000000, 3)
            print(f'\n>>>>>>>> PESO CHAPA 1020/1045: {peso} KG <<<<<<<<\n')
            preço = round(peso * 7, 3)
            print(f'>>>>>>>> PREÇO: R$ {preço} <<<<<<<<\n')
            print('DEFINA AS DIMENSÕES FINAIS DA PEÇA') ###DIMENSOES FINAIS CHAPA 1020###
            altura1 = ler_valores('ALTURA FINAL: ', conversao=float)
            largura1 = ler_valores('LARGURA FINAL: ', conversao=float)
            comprimento1 = ler_valores('COMPRIMENTO FINAL: ', conversao=float)
            peso1 = largura1 * altura1 * comprimento1 * 7.85 / 1000000
            print(f'\n>>>>>>>> PESO FINAL DA PEÇA: {peso1} KG <<<<<<<<\n')
        elif material == "B": ###CALCULO BARRA###
            diametro = ler_valores('DIAMETRO: ', conversao=float)
            comprimento = ler_valores('COMPRIMENTO: ', conversao=float)
            peso = (diametro * diametro * 3.1416 * 7.85 / 4000) * (comprimento / 1000)
            print(f'\n>>>>>>>> PESO BARRA 1020/1045: {peso} KG <<<<<<<< \n') ###PESO###
            preço = peso * 7
            print(f'>>>>>>>> PREÇO: R$ {preço} <<<<<<<<\n') ###PREÇO###
            print('DEFINA AS DIMENSÕES FINAIS DA PEÇA') ###DIMENSOES FINAIS BARRA 1020###
            diametro1 = ler_valores('DIAMETRO FINAL: ', conversao=float)
            comprimento1 = ler_valores('COMPRIMENTO FINAL: ', conversao=float)
            peso1 = (diametro1 * diametro1 * 3.1416 * 7.85 / 4000) * (comprimento1 / 1000)
            print(f'\n>>>>>>>> PESO FINAL DA PEÇA {peso1} KG <<<<<<<<\n')

        tempera = ler_valores("POSSUI TEMPERA? (S/N) ", conversao=lambda s: s.upper(), valores_validos=['S', 'N'])
        if tempera == "S":
            custotratamento = 6.10 * peso1
            print(f'\n>>>>>>>> TEMPERA: R$ {custotratamento} <<<<<<<<\n')
        elif tempera == "N":
            custotratamento = 0
        oxidacao = ler_valores("POSSUI OXIDAÇÃO? (S/N) ", conversao=lambda s: s.upper(), valores_validos=['S', 'N']) ###OXIDAÇÃO###
        if oxidacao == "S":
            custooxidacao = 2 * peso1
            print(f'\n>>>>>>>> OXIDAÇÃO: R$ {custooxidacao} <<<<<<<<\n')
        elif oxidacao == "N":
            custooxidacao = 0
            print('\n')
```

Repare que `\n` pode ficar na própria string, não precisa colocá-lo separadamente. Outro detalhe é que `print` não retorna nada (tecnicamente, ele retorna sempre `None`), então não faz sentido fazer `resultado = print(etc)`. Faça apenas `print(etc)` e pronto (até porque você não está usando essas variáveis `resultado` para nada, e mesmo que usasse, o valor delas seria `None`, então elas são desnecessárias de qualquer maneira e podem ser removidas).

[Uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/468360/112052) estava sugerindo criar uma função e chamar ela mesma dentro do `except` ([antes de ser editada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/0cf72a35-6e22-4bca-8fe4-7a57674c2289/view-source)), o que é um uso totalmente errado de [recursão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438762/112052) (que é quando uma função chama ela mesma, saiba mais lendo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052)). Apesar de "funcionar", depois de um certo número de iterações, pode haver um [estouro de pilha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001) (já usando o *loop* acima, ele pode se repetir quantas vezes quiser, que não haverá este problema). <sup><sub>*Agora a resposta foi editada e a recursão foi retirada, menos mal.*</sub></sup>

---

Outra opção é usar a função `ler_valores` para criar versões mais especializadas dela. Por exemplo:

```
def ler_float(mensagem, mensagem_erro=None):
    return ler_valores(mensagem, mensagem_erro, conversao=float)

def ler_sn(mensagem, mensagem_erro=None): # lê opção sim ou não
    return ler_valores(mensagem, mensagem_erro, conversao=lambda s: s.upper(), valores_validos=['S', 'N'])
```

Aí basta fazer algo como:

```
altura = ler_float('ALTURA: ')
largura = ler_float('LARGURA: ')
etc...

tempera = ler_sn("POSSUI TEMPERA? (S/N) ")
```

Se bem que dá para fazer ainda:

```
def ler_varios_float(*mensagens):
    return [ ler_float(mensagem) for mensagem in mensagens ]

...
altura, largura, comprimento = ler_varios_float('ALTURA: ', 'LARGURA: ', 'COMPRIMENTO: ')
...
altura1, largura1, comprimento1 = ler_varios_float('ALTURA FINAL: ', 'LARGURA FINAL: ', 'COMPRIMENTO FINAL: ')
etc...
```

---

O *loop* não inclui uma opção para sair, então o programa fica se repetindo indefinidamente. Uma opção seria colocar algum valor para que o mesmo saia, algo assim:

```
tipos_validos = [ '1020', '1045', '4340', '8620', '0' ]

while True:
    print("Utilize apenas valores com ponto, e não virgula!\n")
    tipo = ler_valores(f'Digite o tipo ({", ".join(map(str, tipos_validos))}) ou "0" para sair: ', valores_validos=tipos_validos)
    if tipo == '0': # não precisa converter para int, é meio redundante aqui
        break # digitou zero, sai do loop
    if tipo == "1020" or tipo == "1045":
        etc...
```

Comment: (Tive 3 ótimas respostas entao provalvemente vou repetir esse comentário para as 3, mas...) Que aula!! Hahaha bastante informação nova para eu assimilar, estou estudando faz poucos dias. Vou levar um tempo para entender todos os códigos novos que foram inseridos por vocês, mas desde já muitissimo obrigado! Já foi muito esclarecedor. <3 Obrigado por dedicar seu tempo pra me ajudar. Abração!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar while's ao invés de if's e aí ele só vai passar dessa parte quando os valores forem válidos.

```
while True:
    print("Utilize apenas valores com ponto, e não virgula!" '\n')
    
    tipo = input ("1020, 1045, 4340, ou 8620? ")
    while(tipo != "1020" and tipo != "1045"):
        tipo = input ("Valor inválido. 1020, 1045, 4340, ou 8620? ")

    material = input('Chapa (C) ou barra (B)? ').upper()
    while (material != 'C' and material != 'B'):
        material = input('Material inválido. Chapa (C) ou barra (B)? ').upper()

    if (material == "C"): ###CALCULO CHAPA###
        aux = True
        while(aux):
            try:
                altura = float(input('ALTURA: '))
                largura = float (input ('LARGURA: '))
                comprimento = float (input ('COMPRIMENTO: '))
                peso= round ((altura * largura * comprimento * 7.85 / 1000000),3)
                resultado=print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> PESO CHAPA 1020/1045: {peso} KG <<<<<<<<\n')
                preço = round ((peso * 7),3)
                print (f'>>>>>>>> PREÇO: R$ {preço} <<<<<<<<\n')
                aux = False
            except:
                print('Valores inválidos.')

        aux = True
        while(aux):
            try:
                print ('DEFINA AS DIMENSÕES FINAIS DA PEÇA') ###DIMENSOES FINAIS CHAPA 1020###
                altura1 = float (input ("ALTURA FINAL: "))
                largura1 = float (input ("LARGURA FINAL: "))
                comprimento1 = float (input ("COMPRIMENTO FINAL: "))
                peso1= largura1 * altura1 * comprimento1 * 7.85 / 1000000
                aux = False
            except:
                print('Valores inválidos')
        resultado1=print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> PESO FINAL DA PEÇA: {peso1} KG <<<<<<<<\n')

    else: ###CALCULO BARRA###
        aux = True
        while(aux):
            try:
                diametro = float(input('DIAMETRO: '))
                comprimento = float (input ('COMPRIMENTO: '))
                peso= (diametro * diametro * 3.1416 * 7.85 / 4000) * (comprimento/1000)
                resultado=print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> PESO BARRA 1020/1045: {peso} KG <<<<<<<< \n') ###PESO###
                preço = peso * 7
                print (f'>>>>>>>> PREÇO: R$ {preço} <<<<<<<<\n') ###PREÇO###
                aux = False
            except:
                print('Valores inválidos')

        aux = True 
        while(aux):
            try:
                print ('DEFINA AS DIMENSÕES FINAIS DA PEÇA') ###DIMENSOES FINAIS BARRA 1020###
                diametro1 = float (input ("DIAMETRO FINAL: "))
                comprimento1 = float (input ("COMPRIMENTO FINAL: "))
                peso1 = (diametro1 * diametro1 * 3.1416 * 7.85 / 4000) * (comprimento1/1000)
                resultado1=print (f'\n>>>>>>>> PESO FINAL DA PEÇA {peso1} KG <<<<<<<<\n')  
                aux = False
            except:
                print('Valores inválidos')     

    tempera = input("POSSUI TEMPERA? (S/N) ").upper() ###TEMPERA###
    while (tempera != 'S' and tempera != 'N'):
        tempera = input("Resposta inválida. POSSUI TEMPERA? (S/N) ").upper()

    if (tempera == "S"):
        custotratamento= 6.10 * peso1
        print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> TEMPERA: R$ {custotratamento} <<<<<<<<\n')
    else:
        custotratamento = 0

    oxidacao = input ("POSSUI OXIDAÇÃO? (S/N) ").upper() ###OXIDAÇÃO###
    while (oxidacao != 'S' and oxidacao != 'N'):
        oxidacao = input ("Resposta inválida. POSSUI OXIDAÇÃO? (S/N) ").upper()

    if (oxidacao == "S"):
        custooxidacao= 2 * peso1
        print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> OXIDAÇÃO: R$ {custooxidacao} <<<<<<<<\n')
    else:
        custooxidacao = 0
        print ('\n')
    print('FIM')
    print('')
```

Na parte de conferir as respostas ele passa tudo pra letra maiúscula utilizando a função `upper`, então não precisa botar duas comparações pois sempre vai ser em letra maíuscula.

Comment: Essa não é a melhor forma para consertar isso, quando eu chegar em casa vou lhe mostrar uma solução melhor. Mas essa "gambiarra" deve funcionar se você estiver com muita pressa

Comment: Não estou com pressa não hahahah se puder mostrar depois a outra forma (se for diferente dos outros dos outros comentarios) eu vou ler atentamente. Estou começando entao qualquer dica de alguem mais experiente já é super válida! Desde já muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Editei minha resposta. Agora a solução está bem melhor!

Comment: Mais uma aula que recebo! Hahahaha brigadão Natan. Vou olhar com calma e estudar para entender toda a estrutura. Como estou começando eu olho e ainda não entendo algumas coisas, mas me ajudou muito! Muitissimo obrigado por dedicar seu tempo pra me ajudar. Grande abraço!!

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Pelo o que eu entendi o erro está acontecendo nos inputs, em que se a pessoa colocar um valor fora do pedido da erro, se for isso você pode fazer isso:

```
while True:
    print("Utilize apenas valores com ponto, e não virgula!" '\n')
    #a questão da vígula você pode resolver com um replace:
    #numero_float = float(str(variavel_input).replace(',', '.'))
    #A vírgula será substituida por ponto
    tipo = input ("1020, 1045, 4340, ou 8620? ")

    valores_possiveis = [1020,1045,4340,8620] #novo
    if int(tipo) in valores_possiveis: #verifica
        if (tipo == "1020" or tipo == "1045"): ###1020###
            material = input('Chapa (C) ou barra (B)? ')
            
            ##ALTERAÇÃO
            lista_materiais = ['C', 'B'] #Quais os materiais possiveis
            meterial = material.upper()  #Se acaso a letra fornecida estiver em minuscula

            if meterial in lista_materiais: #Verifica se o material fornecido esta na lista
                if (material == "C" or material == "c"): ###CALCULO CHAPA###
                    altura = float(input('ALTURA: '))
                    largura = float (input ('LARGURA: '))
                    comprimento = float (input ('COMPRIMENTO: '))
                    peso= round ((altura * largura * comprimento * 7.85 / 1000000),3)
                    resultado=print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> PESO CHAPA 1020/1045: {peso} KG <<<<<<<<\n')
                    preço = round ((peso * 7),3)
                    print (f'>>>>>>>> PREÇO: R$ {preço} <<<<<<<<\n')
                    print ('DEFINA AS DIMENSÕES FINAIS DA PEÇA') ###DIMENSOES FINAIS CHAPA 1020###
                    altura1 = float (input ("ALTURA FINAL: "))
                    largura1 = float (input ("LARGURA FINAL: "))
                    comprimento1 = float (input ("COMPRIMENTO FINAL: "))
                    peso1= largura1 * altura1 * comprimento1 * 7.85 / 1000000
                    resultado1=print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> PESO FINAL DA PEÇA: {peso1} KG <<<<<<<<\n')
                elif (material == "B" or material == "b"): ###CALCULO BARRA###
                    diametro = float(input('DIAMETRO: '))
                    comprimento = float (input ('COMPRIMENTO: '))
                    peso= (diametro * diametro * 3.1416 * 7.85 / 4000) * (comprimento/1000)
                    resultado=print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> PESO BARRA 1020/1045: {peso} KG <<<<<<<< \n') ###PESO###
                    preço = peso * 7
                    print (f'>>>>>>>> PREÇO: R$ {preço} <<<<<<<<\n') ###PREÇO###
                    print ('DEFINA AS DIMENSÕES FINAIS DA PEÇA') ###DIMENSOES FINAIS BARRA 1020###
                    diametro1 = float (input ("DIAMETRO FINAL: "))
                    comprimento1 = float (input ("COMPRIMENTO FINAL: "))
                    peso1 = (diametro1 * diametro1 * 3.1416 * 7.85 / 4000) * (comprimento1/1000)
                    resultado1=print (f'\n>>>>>>>> PESO FINAL DA PEÇA {peso1} KG <<<<<<<<\n')                       
                tempera = input ("POSSUI TEMPERA? (S/N) ") ###TEMPERA###

                ##ALTERAÇÃO
                tempera = tempera.upper() #colocando em maiuscula
                if tempera in ['S', 'N']:
                
                    if (tempera == "S" or tempera == "s"):
                        custotratamento= 6.10 * peso1
                        print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> TEMPERA: R$ {custotratamento} <<<<<<<<\n')
                    elif (tempera == "N" or tempera == "n"):
                        custotratamento = 0

                    oxidacao = (input("POSSUI OXIDAÇÃO? (S/N) ")).upper() #Coloquei em maiuscula  ###OXIDAÇÃO###

                    ##ALTERAÇÃO
                    if oxidacao in ['S', 'N']:
                    
                        if (oxidacao == "S" or oxidacao == "s"):
                            custooxidacao= 2 * peso1
                            print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> OXIDAÇÃO: R$ {custooxidacao} <<<<<<<<\n')
                        elif (oxidacao == "n" or oxidacao == "N"):
                            custooxidacao = 0
                            print ('\n')
    else:
        print('Digite um valor válido!\n')
```

Ou simplesmente colocar um try e except:

```
while True:
    print("Utilize apenas valores com ponto, e não virgula!" '\n')
    tipo = input ("1020, 1045, 4340, ou 8620? ")
    try:
        if (tipo == "1020" or tipo == "1045"): ###1020###
            material = input('Chapa (C) ou barra (B)? ')
            if (material == "C" or material == "c"): ###CALCULO CHAPA###
                altura = float(input('ALTURA: '))
                largura = float (input ('LARGURA: '))
                comprimento = float (input ('COMPRIMENTO: '))
                peso= round ((altura * largura * comprimento * 7.85 / 1000000),3)
                resultado=print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> PESO CHAPA 1020/1045: {peso} KG <<<<<<<<\n')
                preço = round ((peso * 7),3)
                print (f'>>>>>>>> PREÇO: R$ {preço} <<<<<<<<\n')
                print ('DEFINA AS DIMENSÕES FINAIS DA PEÇA') ###DIMENSOES FINAIS CHAPA 1020###
                altura1 = float (input ("ALTURA FINAL: "))
                largura1 = float (input ("LARGURA FINAL: "))
                comprimento1 = float (input ("COMPRIMENTO FINAL: "))
                peso1= largura1 * altura1 * comprimento1 * 7.85 / 1000000
                resultado1=print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> PESO FINAL DA PEÇA: {peso1} KG <<<<<<<<\n')
            elif (material == "B" or material == "b"): ###CALCULO BARRA###
                diametro = float(input('DIAMETRO: '))
                comprimento = float (input ('COMPRIMENTO: '))
                peso= (diametro * diametro * 3.1416 * 7.85 / 4000) * (comprimento/1000)
                resultado=print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> PESO BARRA 1020/1045: {peso} KG <<<<<<<< \n') ###PESO###
                preço = peso * 7
                print (f'>>>>>>>> PREÇO: R$ {preço} <<<<<<<<\n') ###PREÇO###
                print ('DEFINA AS DIMENSÕES FINAIS DA PEÇA') ###DIMENSOES FINAIS BARRA 1020###
                diametro1 = float (input ("DIAMETRO FINAL: "))
                comprimento1 = float (input ("COMPRIMENTO FINAL: "))
                peso1 = (diametro1 * diametro1 * 3.1416 * 7.85 / 4000) * (comprimento1/1000)
                resultado1=print (f'\n>>>>>>>> PESO FINAL DA PEÇA {peso1} KG <<<<<<<<\n')                       
            tempera = input ("POSSUI TEMPERA? (S/N) ") ###TEMPERA###
            if (tempera == "S" or tempera == "s"):
                custotratamento= 6.10 * peso1
                print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> TEMPERA: R$ {custotratamento} <<<<<<<<\n')
            elif (tempera == "N" or tempera == "n"):
                custotratamento = 0
            oxidacao = input ("POSSUI OXIDAÇÃO? (S/N) ") ###OXIDAÇÃO###
            if (oxidacao == "S" or oxidacao == "s"):
                custooxidacao= 2 * peso1
                print ('\n' f'>>>>>>>> OXIDAÇÃO: R$ {custooxidacao} <<<<<<<<\n')
            elif (oxidacao == "n" or oxidacao == "N"):
                custooxidacao = 0
                print ('\n')
    except:
        print('Os dados informados não são válidos')
```

Espero ter ajudado! Abraço!

Comment: (Tive 3 ótimas respostas entao provalvemente vou repetir esse comentário para as 3, mas...) Que aula!! Hahaha bastante informação nova para eu assimilar, estou estudando faz poucos dias. Vou levar um tempo para entender todos os códigos novos que foram inseridos por vocês, mas desde já muitissimo obrigado! Esse da vírgula vai me ajudar bastante, toda hora me confundo heheh Obrigado por dedicar seu tempo pra me ajudar. <3 Abração!