# O que é memoização?

Tags: terminologia

Vi na pergunta [Como implementar memoização em uma função PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104014/como-implementar-memoiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-php) aparecer o termo "memoização".

A primeira impressão que tive é que esse termo estava relacionado a "memorização" ou "evitar reprocessamento". É apenas isso ou é algo mais abrangente?

De onde surgiu e o que significa esse termo?

Qualquer linguagem de programação pode usar essa "memoização"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A origem etimológica é a mesma do termo "memorização", sendo os dois [cognatos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognato). [Do artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) (tradução livre),

> O termo "memoization" ou "memoisation" foi inventado por Donald Michie em 1968 e é derivado da palavra latina "memorandum" ("a ser lembrado"), geralmente truncado como "memo" na língua inglesa, e assim carrega o significado de "Transformando os resultados de uma função em algo a ser lembrado". Enquanto "memoization" pode ser confundido com "memorization" (porque eles são cognatos etimológicos), "memoization" tem um significado especializado em computação.

Memoização é um subtipo de [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)).