# Como definir o maior número primo dentro de um número dado?

Tags: python

Por exemplo, você dá o número 100 e o maior número primo dentro de 100 é 97. Como posso programar isso?

"Escreva a função maior_primo que recebe um número inteiro maior ou igual a 2 como parâmetro e devolve o maior número primo menor ou igual ao número passado à função

Note que

- `maior_primo(100)` deve devolver 97
- `maior_primo(7)` deve devolver 7

Dica: escreva uma função éPrimo(k) e faça um laço percorrendo os números até o número dado checando se o número é primo ou não; se for, guarde numa variável. Ao fim do laço, o valor armazenado na variável é o maior primo encontrado."

Essa é a pergunta. Podem me ajudar? Fiz alguns testes mas não fazem o menor sentido. Segue um dos testes:

```
def maior_primo(p):
    while p >= 2:
        i = p - 1
        p % 1 == 0
        return p


def éPrimo(k):
    i = 2
    é_primo = 0
    while i < k:
        if k % i ==0:
            break
        else:
            i = i+1
    if i == k:
        é_primo = False
        return False
    else:
        é_primo = True
        return True
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Já ouviu falar do [Crivo de Erastótenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes?wprov=sfsi1)?

Answer (score 5):

> **UPDATE**: o Anderson Carlos Woss tem uma ótima resposta sobre o Crivo, respondida um mês antes da minha: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206144/64969

Eu fui membro da equipe de Maratona de Programação da minha faculdade. Éramos os *Colecionadores de Balões*, da UECE. E primos era uma quase constante durante as questões da Maratona, então precisávamos de algo rápido, prático e eficiente, muito eficiente.

O algoritmo que a gente usava para calcular os números primos era o [Crivo de Eratóstenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes?wprov=sfsi1). Por que ele era eficiente? Porque ele calculava todos os primos menores do que ou igual a `n` em um tempo de `o(n log log n)`; e só precisava fazer isso uma vez, poderíamos armazenar esse valor calculado no começo do programa e usá-lo adiante. Também preciso ressaltar que o Crivo exige memória `o(n)`, então só pode ser usada para números pequenos (como 700 milhões em C, talvez uns 100 milhões em Python, por exemplo).

Como funciona esse algoritmo? Bem, ele funciona marcando as posições sabidamente não primas/números compostos de um vetor com base nos primos que ele descobre. No final do Crivo, todas as posições não marcadas que restaram são números sabidamente primos.

## Usando o vetor de primos resultante para calcular o maior primo menor que `n`

Suponha que eu tenha um vetor chamado `numero_eh_primo` de booleanos. Ele precisa ter pelo menos `n + 1` posições para dar certo o Crivo. Obviamente o Crivo já rodou e temos esse vetor preenchido da seguinte maneira:

- `numero_eh_primo[i]` é verdadeira se `i` for primo
- `numero_eh_primo[i]` é falsa se `i` for composto

Para descobrir qual o maior primo menor do que ou igual a `n`, basta percorrer o vetor a partir de `n`, decrementadando uma unidade caso a posição seja falsa e retornar o primeiro índice encontrada caso o valor seja verdadeiro.

### Aplicando [memoização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33440/64969)

Se eu tiver bastante memória, posso aplicar uma estratégia de [memoização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/175413/64969) para tornar futuras consultas ao mesmo número `n` de ordem constante. Para isso, preciso de um vetor auxiliar chamado `maior_primo_menorque`, que vai retornar o maior primo maior do que ou igual ao índice passado. Por exemplo: `maior_primo_menorque[100]` retorna 97 quando está preenchido.

Como saber se o valor não está preenchido? Simples, se estiver nulo. Estando nulo, como preencher? Bem, vamos ao algoritmo de memoização:

```
def get_maior_primo(n):
    if maior_primo_menorque[n]:
        return maior_primo_menorque[n]
   else:
        if numero_eh_primo[n]:
            maior_primo_menorque[n] = n
            return n
       else:
            maior_primo_menorque[n] = get_maior_primo(n - 1)
            return maior_primo_menorque[n]
```

## O Crivo de Eratóstenes

Até agora eu só falei que usava o Crivo, mas em nenhum momento eu falei como funciona esse Crivo. Vamos lá.

O Crivo começa com um vetor com `n + 1` posições, tudo setada como verdade a priori (ie, são possíveis primos). Então, desconsideramos os números 0 e 1, marcando eles como falsos. Após isso, percorremos o vetor sequencialmente, até achar um índice que esteja setado como verdade. Nesse momento, achamos um primo verdadeiro, então devemos marcar todos os seus múltiplos como falsos; depois de marcar os múltiplos como falsos, voltamos a percorrer sequencialmente o vetor.

```
def crivo(n, vetor_crivo_inicializado_como_true):
    vetor = vetor_crivo_inicializado_como_true
    vetor[0] = False
    vetor[1] = False

    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        if vetor[i]:
            # achou um primo, vamos marcar todos os múltiplos relevantes
            marcar_multiplos(n, vetor, i)

def marcar_multiplos(n, vetor_crivo, primo):
    for i in range(primo*primo, n + 1, primo):
        vetor_crivo[i] = False
```

Note a otimização de começar a marcar os múltiplos a partir do quadrado do primo: todo múltiplo desse primo com outro valor já foi marcado em um passo anterior. Por exemplo, com o primo encontrado 5, eu já marquei os números 10 (múltiplo de 2), 15 (múltiplo de 3) e 20 (múltiplo de 2), sendo o primeiro número composto inédito o quadrado de 5, 25.

> O [@LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/18246/linq) me deu a dica de fazer um MCVE, vou mandar um assim que possível

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a função criada pelo Miguel no post citado nos comentários:

**Código1:**

```
def maior_primo(n):
    for num in reversed(range(1,n+1)):
        if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,num)):
            return num
```

**Output1:**

```
maior_primo(100) 
>>>97
```

---

Ou pode utilizar essa função que criei, tentando deixar mais intuitivo o processo e facilitar o seu entendimento:

**Código2:**

```
def maior_primo(n):

    primos = []
    for i in range(n):
        c = 0
        for j in range(n):
            if i%(j+1) == 0: 
                c += 1
        if c == 2:
            primos.append(i)

    return(max(primos))
```

**Output2:**

```
maior_primo(100)
>>> 97
```

---

A ideia por trás dela é a seguinte:

1. Para cada número de 1 até o número inserido pelo usuário ao chamar a função:
2. Verifique se o resto da divisão desse número pelos números de 1 até ele mesmo, é igual a 0.
3. Se for igual a 0, some 1 ao contador.
4. Se ao final das iterações o contador estiver com o valor 2, isso quer dizer que o número é divisível somente por 2 números no loop de 1 até ele mesmo; ou seja, é um número primo.
5. Se o número for primo, vou guardá-lo numa lista chamada `primos`
6. Depois de testar todos os números no intervalo
7. Vou retornar para o usuário o maior valor existente na lista `primos`.

Esse valor será o maior número primo no intervalo de 1 até o número inserido.

Comment: 1 não é primo, por favor não conte o 1!

Comment: Olá, eu só acho que com a tua função estás a fazer mais do que o que realmente precisas, precisas só de um num, devias retornar logo porque escusas de os percorrer a todos e guardar numa lista e depois ainda fazer o `max()`. Podes fazer `for I in reversed(range(n)):` e retornas logo quando encontras o primeiro

Comment: @Wtrmute 1 normalmente não é primo :) Tem um vídeo do canal Numberphile no YouTube explicando porque normalmente se exclue o 1 do conjunto dos primos

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz um pequena alteração no código do @dot.PY, pois testando com 101 como número de entrada, o retorno para o maior primo foi 97 - quando o maior é o próprio 101. Vejam se faz sentido:

```
def maior_primo(entrada):
primos = []
for inc in range(entrada + 1):
    cont = 0
    for jinc in range(entrada + 1):
        if inc % (jinc + 1) == 0:
            cont += 1
    if cont == 2:
        primos.append(inc)
return(max(primos))
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Fiz um código buscando diminuir a utilização de outras bibliotecas. Segue:

```
def maior_primo(n):
k = n        
while k > 1 and é_primo(k)==False:
    k = k - 1
return k

def é_primo(k):

primo = True    
div = 2

while k>div:
    
    if k % div == 0:
        primo = False
    div = div + 1
    
return primo
```

Espero que ajude!
Atenciosamente,

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi do seu enunciado, você deseja implementar um código que seja capaz de exibir o **maior número primo menor ou igual ao número "n"**.

Para resolver esta questão você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
def maior_primo(n):
    for c in range(n, 1, -1):
        if primo(c):
            return c


def primo(m):
    i = 1
    cont = 0
    while i <= m:
        if m % i == 0:
            cont += 1
        i += 1
        if cont > 2:
            return False
    return True


num = int(input('Digite um número inteiro maior que "1": '))

print(f'O maior número primo menor ou igual a "{num}" é: {maior_primo(num)}')
```

Quando executamos este código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite um número inteiro maior que "1":`. Neste momento devemos digite um número inteiro **maior que 1** e pressionar enter.

A partir desse momento o valor é passado como parâmetro para a função `maior_primo()`. Chegando lá, o bloco `for` irá iterar - quantas vezes for necessário - sobre o **range(n, 1, -1)**. Em cada uma dessas iterações o bloco `if` perguntará à função `primo()` se o valor de `c` é de fato um número primo. Então, a função `primo()` calculará os divisores de `c` e se o número de divisores for igual à **2**, enviará o valor **True** como resposta ao bloco `if` da função `maior_primo()`. Caso contrário, enviará **False** como resposta.

Caso o `if` da função `maior_primo()` receba **False** como resposta da função `primo()`, o for encerrará a iteração atual e executará a próxima. Caso o `if` da função `maior_primo` receba **True** como resposta da função `primo()`, será exibido o **retorno** da função e o script será automaticamente encerrado.

**Nota:**

Pelo fato do bloco `for`, da função `exibir_primo()`, percorrer o range de forma decrescente a partir do **maior** valor - **n** - e encerrar sua execução logo após encontrar o **1º primo**, o tal código se demonstra bem eficiente. Pois, o mesmo só executará as iterações que forem exclusivamente necessárias para encontrar o **primeiro primo**. Após ele encontrar o primeiro primo, de imediato é exibido o retorno e, também, é encerrado a execução do script.

**Vamos testar o código?**

**Exemplo 1**

Digitando o valor **7**, receberemos como saída:

```
O maior número primo menor ou igual a "7" é: 7
```

Neste caso a entrada foi um número primo - **7** - e a saída foi o **maior número primo igual a 7**.

**Exemplo 2**

Digitando o valor **100**, receberemos como saída:

```
O maior número primo menor ou igual a "100" é: 97
```

Neste caso a entrada foi um número não primo - **100** - e a saída foi o **maior número primo menor que 100**, que no caso é **97**.

**Resumo:**

Este código é capaz de calcular e exibir o **maior número primo menor ou igual ao número "n"**.

Comment: Você não precisa calcular quantos divisores o número possui para definir se o número é primo. Se o divisor do número é diferente de 1 e dele mesmo (m), o número m já não é primo.

Comment: Por exemplo, não preciso verificar de 1 até 100.000 para contar que o número 100.000 possui 36 divisores e, por isso, não é primo. Já no 2 eu concluo que ele não é primo por ser par.

Comment: @Woss, obrigado pela observação. Vou corrigir.

Comment: @Woss, no bloco if da função `primo()`, se eu deslocar uma tabulação para direita, trocando o sinal `!=` por `>` melhora a performance?

Answer (score 0):

Eu achei uma forma que imagino ser simples e efetiva, sem usar for ou coisas do tipo:

```
def maior_primo(n):
div=1
uau=True   
cont=0
while div <=n and uau:
    if n%div== 0:
        cont=cont+1  
    if cont>=3:
        cont=1
        n=n-1
        div=1
    if cont==2 and n==div:
         uau=False   
    div=div+1
return n
```

Espero que seja útil.