# Qual a forma mais rápida de se calcular a sequencia de fibonacci

Tags: c, matemática

Estou fazendo uma questão que e [Fibonacci de Novo!](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1531) os testes dão o resultado esperado só que dá    Time limit exceeded, queria se tem uma forma mais rápida de se calcular

Meu código

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fat(int num);

int main()
{
  int numero, resto;
  while(scanf("%d %d", &numero, &resto) != EOF)
  {
    printf("%d\n", fat(fat(numero))%resto);
  }
}

int fat(int num)
{
  int numero1 = 0, numero2 = 1, soma;

  for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    soma = numero1 + numero2;
    numero2 = numero1;
    numero1 = soma;
  }
  return numero1;
}
```

Comment: Tempo limite excedido pode indicar que o tempo não está aceitável para grandes entradas. Já tentou com as entradas extremas?

Comment: Já testou também o `ctrl+d` para simular fim da entrada padrão?

Comment: Aproveitando, o segredo está no módulo, para otimizar o cálculo

Comment: Olá Jefferson entradas só testei as que a questão forneceu,  como assim o segredo está no módulo, teria outra maneira de fazer sem a utilização do operador de resto ?

Comment: "Como assim o segredo está no módulo?" ==> Através da operação de módulo (ou de resto, caso prefira chamá-la assim), você obtém resultados muito interessantes que permitem fazer uma quantidade muito menor de operações e chegar no mesmo resultado. Veja minha resposta para maiores detalhes

Comment: Na verdade, Rafael Marques, a forma mais rápida de calcular é usando um programa matemático para calcular até o ponto que dá overflow e então, sabendo a sequência até onde os valores são válidos, salvar em array de constantes a sequência. Assim, pode-se apenas acessar o número de Fibonacci na memória ao invés de calcular. Se for usar tipo `int`, como o `fib(46)` cabe em tipo `int` enquanto `fib(47)` dá overflow, então não serão necessárias nem 50 células para salvar os valores válidos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primeiro ponto, precisamos conhecer o comportamento da função para calcular Fibonacci de um número. Temos diversas alternativas. Primeiro, começar pela definição recursiva da função de Fibonacci:

```python
def fib(n):
  if n == 1 or n == 2:
    return 1
  else:
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Se você analizar a fundo, vai perceber que a única opção de um valor ser acrescentado ao número de retorno é quando temos na recursão a chamada para `fib(1)` ou `fib(2)`. Mas, e quantas chamadas de função são feitas ao todo? Para responder a essa pergunta, criei uma função que batizei de `meta_fib`. Além de contar as mesmas chamadas de função do retorno de Fibonacci, também adiciono um a cada chamada recursiva. Então, `meta_fib` é descrita como:

```python
def meta_fib(n):
  if n == 1 or n == 2:
    return 1
  else:
    return 1 + meta_fib(n - 1) + meta_fib(n - 2)
```

`meta_fib(i)`, então, vai retornar quantas chamadas de função são feitas. [Resolvi comparar o quanto `meta_fib` crescia em comparação a `fib`](https://ideone.com/4kfNI6). Então, aparentemente, `meta_fib(a) = 2*fib(a) - 1`. Só que a função de Fibonacci tem crescimento exponencial. O @Ricardo Ribeiro colocou a fórmula em [sua reposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/294705/64969) (retornaremos a ela mais tarde):

[image: fórmula de Fibonacci]

Então, a quantidade de chamadas à função `fib` é:

[image: quantas chamadas recursivas são feitas para calcular fib?]

Ok, temos uma estratégia. Olhemos o enunciado para saber se a estratégia pode ser minimamente viável. Talvez com algumas dezenas de milhões de operações eu consiga fazer o cálculo com sucesso... note que (1 - φ) é um valor entre 0 e 1, portanto elevar ele a um número maior que 1 deixará ele mais próximo de zero.

> [...] Sua tarefa é simples, calcular o valor do resto de Fib( Fib( N ) ) por M.
>
> #### Entrada
>
> A entrada é composta por vários casos de teste e termina com EOF. Cada caso de teste consiste de uma linha com dois inteiros N e M (1 ≤ N ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>, 2 ≤ M ≤ 10<sup>6</sup>).

É... eles pedem para calcular até 1 bilhão... Creio que φ<sup>10<sup>9</sup></sup> é um pouco maior do que meu limite imaginário de alguns milhões de operações...

E se eu fizer com [memoização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175412/64969)? Bem, com isso eu garanto que eu não desço recursivamente duas vezes pelo mesmo `fib(n)`. Com memoização, calcular `fib(n + 2)` fica mais ou menos assim (colocar com `*` os valores memoizados):

```python
fib(n + 2) =
fib(n + 1) + fib(n)* =
fib(n)* + fib(n)* + fib(n - 1)*
```

E, nesse cálculo, os valores e `fib(n + 1)` e `fib(n + 2)` são memoizados ao serem calculados. E o quanto de memória eu precisaria para memoizar tudo? É um inteiro para cada índice... ou seja, precisaria de 10<sup>9</sup> inteiros para tentar memoizar todas as entradas para `fib(n)`. Mas a questão é que não estamos calculando `fib(n)`, mas `fib(fib(n))`, o que exigiria um tanto mais de memória... de toda sorte, 1 bilhão de inteiros já exigiria (para um inteiro de 32 bits) 4GB de RAM **só para o vetor de memoização**. Bem, eu não sei quanto o URI disponibiliza, mas com certeza é menos do que isso...

Então, essa alternativa memoizada *também* está fora de cogitação.

E calcular de forma linear? Como você mesmo, @rafael marques, sugeriu? Bem, é feito de forma linear. Na pior das hipóteses, então, a entrada seria 1 bilhão e, para calcular o Fibonacci só disso, seriam necessárias bilhões de operações. Então, essa alternativa **também** não é viável...

É necessário uma abordagem mais rápida do que [`o(n)`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236960/64969). Talvez uma abordagem `o(log n)` poderia ser aceita, mas acho que uma abordagem `o(1)` é melhor.

Peguemos a fórmula novamente:

[image: fórmula de Fibonacci]

Preste atenção no termo do lado direito: `(1 -  φ)^n/sqrt(5)`. Se você for calcular, verá que o valor absoluto desse número é sempre menor que 0.5. Então, podemos obter o valor de `fib(n)` através da seguinte fórmula:

[image: nova leitura da fórmula de Fibonacci]

> [Fonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding)

Assim sendo, consigo calcular `fib(n)`. Mas... será mesmo? Para tal, precisamos garantir que o número calculado caiba dentro do espaço de memória reservado para tal. Uma variável do tipo `double` só tem 53 bits de mantissa. Isso não é suficiente nem para armazenar a entrada inteira, que pode chegar a 1 bilhão, portanto precisara de uns 62 dígitos para ser armazenado. Então, o tipo `double` não é adequado. E `long double`? Bem, ele é garantidamente não menor que um `double` ([fonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)), mas em nenhum momento eu vi definição garantida dele. Talvez seja um [ponto flutuante extendido do x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format), que usa 64 bits de mantissa ([veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/64969)). Ou seja, nada feito ainda.

Se pelo menos fosse possível usar esse `mod m` em algum lugar...

[image: loading...]

Mas, existe o período de Pisano!!

[image: loaded!!]

O [período de Pisano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) é o tamanho do intervalo em que os números da sequência de Fibonacci começam a se repetir, `mod m`. O interessante desse período é que `fib(n) % m = fib(n % π(m)) % m`, sendo `π(m)` o período de Pisano para o módulo `m`. E o interessante é que `π(m) <= 6*m`. Daí, calcular `fib(n) % m` não é mais dependente de `n`, mas é `o(π(m))`, e como temos que `π(m) = o(m)`, então o cálculo de uma sequência de Fibonacci módulo `m` é `o(m)`. E isso está dentro do nosso aceitável.

Então, com isso, revisando aqui o nosso objeto de cálculo:

[image: fib(fib(n))mod m]

Que portanto é igual a:

[image: fib(fib(n) % pi(m)) % m]

Que portanto é igual a:

[image: fib(fib(n % pi(pi(m))) % pi(m)) % m]

Muito bem, com isso, o cálculo iterativo de `fib` é bom o suficiente. Voltemos a como fazer esse cálculo em breve, pois antes precisamos definir uma outra ponta solta na solução... o valor de `π(m)`.

Diversas outras pessoas já se depararam com a necessidade de fazer o cálculo da função de Fibonacci para números grandes. Como [esse rapaz do artigo](https://medium.com/competitive/huge-fibonacci-number-modulo-m-6b4926a5c836). E, sim, ele foi uma das referências que encontrei quando buscava sobre o cálculo de `π(m)`. Em resumo, é algo muito próximo de calcular o valor de `fib(n)`, mas a ideia é que ao obter o valor 0 e, em seguida, obter o valor 1, entrou-se em laço. O número `n ==> fib(n)%m == 0, fib(n + 1)%m == 1`  é o tamanho do período de Pisano; ou seja, `n <==> π(m)`.

Então, para calcular o `π(m)` é necessário calcular a função de Fibonacci. Para isso, vou usar a adaptação do cálculo iterativo que você fez:

```python
def pisano(m):
    if m == 1:
        return 1
        
    """
    toda sequência tem tamanho par, então posso começar de n = 2 e terminar quando
    obter:
    
    f_n_minus_1 == 0
    f_n == 1
    """
    
    f_n_minus_1 = 1
    f_n = 1
    n = 2
    
    while not(f_n_minus_1 == 0 and f_n == 1):
        f_n_plus_1 = (f_n + f_n_minus_1) % m
        f_n_minus_1 = f_n
        f_n = f_n_plus_1
        n += 1
    return n - 1
```

[Veja funcionando no ideone](https://ideone.com/1tViOS). Note que, aqui, minha validação é para `fib(n - 1) % m == 0, fib(n) % m == 1`, então aqui `n` é `π(m) + 1` no final do laço; por isso que o retorno é `n - 1`, mas claro que isso poderia ser alterado (mas daí os nomes das variável `fib_n`, `fib_n_plus_1` e `fib_n_minus_1` não fariam sentido, teria de renomear).

Então, como proceder com a conta? Poderíamos usar memoização para evitar calcular duas vezes o mesmo valor de `π(x)`. Para tal, o vetor de memória deveria ter o tamanho de mais ou menos 6 milhões de inteiros (limite superior para `π(m), m <= 1000000`, para realizar o cálculo de `π(π(m))`). Vou deixar essa parte com você. E o cálculo da sequência de Fibonacci módulo m, então? Como ficaria?

Se reparou bem, é necessário passar sempre por todos os valores da sequência de Fibonacci menores do que o período para achar o período. Talvez fosse o caso de armazenar esses valores intermediários em um vetor e acessá-los em `o(1)`. Vou deixar para você pensar em como resolver.

Para resolver a questão, precisamos escrever `fib(fib(n))%m`, que batizo de `fib_fib_mod`. Ela seria assim:

```python
def fib_fib_mod(n, m):
  return fib_mod(fib_mod(n, pisano(m)), m)
```

Já `fib_mod`:

```python
def fib_mod(n, m):
  n = n % pisano(m)
  if n == 0:
    return 0
  f_x_minus_1 = 0
  f_x = 1
  x = 1
  while x < n:
    f_x_plus_1 = (f_x + f_x_minus_1) % m
    f_x_minus_1 = f_x
    f_x = f_x_plus_1
    x += 1
  return f_x
```

Deixei o código em Python para que você precise adaptá-lo para C. E, na adpatação, fazer as mudanças necessárias para tentar otimizar o cálculo, como memoizar os diversos cálculos no meio do caminho para evitar repetir cálculos prévios. [Veja funcionando para algumas entradas no ideone](https://ideone.com/LB44B9).

## Conclusão

- esse problema é muito mais de matemática do que programação, não seria possível pensar em resolução para ele sem conhecer as sequências de Pisano
- sempre leia os limites da questão; se a questão disse que o máximo para uma variável é 1 bilhão, então os criadores da prova pensaram em um caso de entrada para 1 bilhão
- mesmo que você tenha uma solução `o(n)`, ele vai ser inutilmente lenta caso o valor de `n` seja muito grande, como 1 bilhão
- teste para casos além dos casos em que o criador da prova mostrou
  aqueles ali são só meros exemplos para você se basear, ter um norte, principalmente no ***formato*** de entrada e saída de dados; muito mais do que outra coisa, as pessoas que criam essas provas gostam de mostrar de maneira a não ter dúvidas qual o formato de entrada e o formato esperado de saída
- as vezes, a melhor otimização em um programa é sair o mais longe possível da programação e usar fórmulas mágicas, como a de cálculo do período de Pisano

Comment: A famosa frase "primeiro resolva o problema, depois escreva o código" se encaixa perfeitamente nessa solução. Só porque precisa escrever um código, não significa que o problema seja de programação.

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se é a mais rápida, mas acredito que essa, se adaptada ao problema, vai  ser aceita!!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double n, x, y, ans;
    scanf("%lf", &n);
    x = (1 + sqrt(5))/2.0;
    y = (1 - sqrt(5))/2.0;
    ans = (pow(x,n) - pow(y,n))/sqrt(5);
    printf("%.1lf\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Acho que você adaptar para resolver a questão em si (Fibonacci do Fibonacci de `n` módulo `p`) deixará melhor a resposta

Answer (score -2):

Tente este codigo: recursivo

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fib(int n)                            
{                                         
  if (n == 1) return 1;                   
    else 
      if (n == 2) return 1;                 
      else return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);  
}                                         
int main(void)
{ 
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("%d\n", fib(n));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: O filho, posta seu excelente código , coelho da programação!!! não dá palpite , posta seu código!! Estamos tentando ajudar!!!

Comment: Servido? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/294998/64969

Comment: Nossa Jefferson que resposta ótima, muito obrigado, vou estudar agora seu código