# Converter Hora 24 horas para 00 horas

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uma conta em int, que preciso voltar ela pra horas, e está funcionando perfeitamente, o erro ocorre quando o horário aparece 24, sendo que ele deveria aparecer 00:00.
Segue como estou fazendo:

```
string horaStg;
decimal valor = int.Parse(item.HoraInicio);
valor = (valor / 60);
var inicio = valor.ToString().Split(char.Parse(","));
string hora = inicio[0];
try
{
    string minuto = "0," + inicio[1];
    string m = Math.Round(decimal.Parse(minuto.ToString()) * 60).ToString();
    horaStg = DateTime.Parse(hora + ":" + m.Substring(0, 2)).ToString("HH:mm");
}
catch
{
    horaStg = DateTime.Parse(hora + ":" + "00").ToString("HH:mm");
}
```

Como posso converter para aparecer as 00:00 ?
Pois da forma que tá quando é meia noite, ele aparece 24 e me retorna o seguinte erro:

> The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

Eu fiz um if, assim:

```
if (hora == "24")
{
    hora = "00";
}
```

Mas não tem alguma conversão que faça diretamente ?

Comment: Que tal usar o módulo? `(valor/60) % 24`

Comment: Poderia me explicar qual a função do % 24 por favor ? Vou fazer o teste aqui.

Comment: @marianac_costa poderia esclarecer melhor o que você quer fazer com esse código, por acaso o seu `item.HoraInicio` seria o total de minutos e você quer converter isso para o formato horas minutos "HH:mm"?

Comment: O `%` é o operador de módulo, ou resto da divisão. Então, 27%24 retornaria 3, que é o resto da divisão; 3 % 24 retorna 3 e 24 % 24 retorna 0, já que é uma divisão sem resto

Comment: Eu usei essa operação nesta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/294998/64969

Comment: Entendi @JeffersonQuesado deu certinho, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Se você pegar sua variável DateTime e fizer um ToString nela passando o formato de horas com a letra "H" maiúscula, já irá aparecer no formato de 00 horas.

Formato "HH" maiúscula aparece no formato 24 horas.
Formato "hh" minúscula aparece no formato 12 horas AM/PM.

Exemplo:

```
DateTime data = new DateTime(2018, 06, 29, 00, 11, 49);

Console.WriteLine(data.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
```