# Há como construir uma aplicação útil baseada totalmente no paradigma funcional?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, programação-funcional, funções-puras

O paradigma funcional, em teoria, é bonito de se ver. [Purismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255557/41056), [imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/41056) e [determinismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102597/o-que-%C3%A9-um-algoritmo-determin%C3%ADstico-e-n%C3%A3o-determin%C3%ADstico). Isso pode facilitar o desenvolvimento, diminuir a incidência de *bugs* e ajudar na manutenibilidade. A partir disso, há como construir uma aplicação útil baseada *totalmente* na programação funcional?

Ao meu ver, qualquer comunicação externa ou *side effect* como:

- imprimir no *console*;
- consumir a data/hora do sistema;
- salvar/recuperar dados de um banco de dados

fere o purismo do paradigma funcional.

Sendo assim, tem como respeitar inteiramente esse paradigma para montar um software "útil"? Por útil quero dizer aplicações que se comuniquem com sistemas externos, como bancos de dados, APIs, e que receba entrada do usuário.

Se eu quiser construir algo, eu deveria ter parte do meu código funcional e a parte *impura* separada em outro paradigma que me permita entrada de dados externos? Em geral, como as linguagens funcionais (F#, Erlang, Elixir, Scala) lidam isso? Ou nem lidam?

Comment: LISP permite você sair um pouco do mundo funcional em Common Lisp, então a saída padrão para linguagens deste paradigma é abrir alguns pontos imperativos por questões pragmáticas. Não lembro exatamente como o outro dialeto majoritário (Scheme) lida com isso, mas eu creio que seja abrindo pontos específicos para ser uma programação imperativa também. Outro ponto para se avaliar é: a solução pode ter uma parte funcional pura que é alimentada por uma camada não funcional, como se o programador deixasse a parte funcional apenas para fazer a computação em si, não para lidar com todos os detalhes...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Há como construir uma aplicação útil baseada totalmente na programação funcional?

Compiladores são úteis? É um domínio onde esse paradigma funciona muito bem.

Big Data, Machine Learning são úteis? Programação funcional se dá muito bem com isso. Talvez não em todas nuances dessas tecnologias, mas em várias delas vai muito bem.

> qualquer comunicação externa fere os pilares do paradigma funcional. Como funciona a construção de uma aplicação com programação funcional? Não existe como respeitar inteiramente esse paradigma para montar algo real/útil?

Pureza de paradigma é difícil de alcançar mesmo. Se quer assim, e nenhuma linguagem que eu conheço é 100% funcional (alguns adaptam o conceito para dizer que sua linguagem é), aí só poderia fazer manipulações de dados existentes no próprio código, nada externo.

Nem imperativo costuma ser 100% puro, ainda que dê.

> Se eu quiser construir algo, eu deveria ter parte do meu código funcional e a parte impura separada em outro paradigma que me permita interação externa?

Basicamente é isso.

> Em geral, como as linguagens funcionais (F#, Erlang/Elixir, Scala) lidam isso? Ou nem lidam?

Essas, em geral, não lidam, elas são funcionais até a página 3 :)

Tem linguagens que usam [Monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)) para tratar de comunicação externa encapsulando o que é impuro do resto do código, assim, de certa forma, podemos continuar considerando como programação funcional já que as regras colocadas no Monad criam um certo determinismo e não causam efeitos colaterais, mantendo a transparência referencial, ou seja, o Monad é puro mesmo que internamente ele faça coisas impuras, ele não se contamina (pelo menos conceitualmente).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).